# How can I do a line break (line continuation) in Python (split up a long line of source code)?

Tags: python, syntax, line-breaks, long-lines

Given:

```
e = 'a' + 'b' + 'c' + 'd'
```

How do I write the above in two lines?

```
e = 'a' + 'b' +
    'c' + 'd'
```

Answer (score 1547, accepted):

What is the line?  You can just have arguments on the next line without any problems:

```
a = dostuff(blahblah1, blahblah2, blahblah3, blahblah4, blahblah5, 
            blahblah6, blahblah7)
```

Otherwise you can do something like this:

```
if (a == True and
    b == False):
```

or with explicit line break:

```
if a == True and \
   b == False:
```

Check the [style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for more information.

Using parentheses, your example can be written over multiple lines:

```
a = ('1' + '2' + '3' +
    '4' + '5')
```

The same effect can be obtained using explicit line break:

```
a = '1' + '2' + '3' + \
    '4' + '5'
```

Note that the style guide says that using the implicit continuation with parentheses is preferred, but in this particular case just adding parentheses around your expression is probably the wrong way to go.

Comment: Actually, you have the style guide's preference exactly backwards.  Implicit continuation is preferred, explicit backslash is to be used only if necessary.

Comment: I think it's saying that if you have brackets around an expression already, use those, but don't put brackets around an expression just for the purpose of breaking it over multiple lines.  No hard-and-fast rule though.  I do think for the line in the question though, a backslash is the way to go.

Comment: That's not correct.  Please edit your answer to reflect what the style guide actually says, rather than stating the opposite.

Comment: Carl: I disagree, this is from the guide: The preferred way of wrapping long lines is by using Python's implied line continuation inside parentheses, brackets and braces.  If necessary, you can add an extra pair of parentheses around an expression, but sometimes using a backslash looks better.

Comment: Jerub: you disagree with Carl, but you quote the guide stating that "The preferred way… is by using Python's implied line continuation inside parentheses…". So you either disagree with Harley, or you lost the meaning of the quote you pasted.

Comment: The thing is, in this case there are _no_ parentheses required.  Sure, you can have them, but why would you put them around the example in the question?  Either way, I'll edit my answer slightly to clarify.

Comment: The key part of the style guide quote is "If necessary, you can add an extra pair of parentheses around an expression, but sometimes using a backslash looks better."  The style guide is *not* saying that you should *add* parentheses, it leaves it to the judgement of the writer.

Comment: Presumably PEP-8 has changed since these comments were added, as it's fairly clear now that parentheses should be added to wrap long lines: "Long lines can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in parentheses."

Comment: @HarleyHolcombe I read that as it being acceptable to add parentheses in order to wrap long lines; if the expressions already had parentheses there would be no need to wrap it. However, it's definitely not 100% clear and I won't quibble over interpretation. The deciding factor for me is that I think it looks better that way :).

Comment: PEP8 did indeed change in 2010 - "sometimes using a backslash looks better" has gone.

Comment: @e100 _"Backslashes may still be appropriate at times."_ is there now in 2014. Dunno if it was gone and then came back or just moved.

Comment: Not super important but because it python I would recomend using `(spam + eggs + foo + bar + moreSpam + moreEggs)` because in python spam and eggs are traditional.

Comment: so if you chain you should use parens around your line breaking chains? i'm pretty frustrated with python coming from c, c++, c# and javascript. Its not as simple as I expected because whitespace does matter, thinking this was less is more but they got me.

Comment: What to do with `ans['Interfaces Declared by Environment'][env_.name][interface_] = None`? This line is too long, but I don't know where to split!

Comment: My IDE yells at me if I have a hanging indent aligned with an indented code block underneath it.  In these cases I frequently remove parentheses and replace them with backslashes so there is a one-character gap.

Comment: Advantage of the parenthesised version: you can put comments after the line break. I often use multiline statements to break a single statement into pieces and comment on each piece. Can't to that with the backslashes.

Comment: Very confusing apparently in the specific case of using `+` string concatenation, normal hanging indent does not work... you MUST (?) enclose the whole thing in parens. E.g.: `1: a = 'this ' + does +` `2:    ' not ' + work`  must be written as `1: a = ('this ' + does +` `2:    ' work ' + fine)`.  Jeeez

Comment: If anyone's wondering where backslash must be used instead of parenthesis: with the `assert` keyword. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3112178/5629418

Comment: @Peter If to make a line of code comprehensible, you need to break it up into multiple lines and put a comment after each, it's a bad sign.  Prefer splitting complex statements into multiple statements, using clear variable names, etc.  Make the code speak for itself, and you can avoid line-by-line comments almost entirely.

Answer (score 307):

From *[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)*:

> **The preferred way of wrapping long lines is by using Python's implied line continuation inside parentheses, brackets and braces.** Long lines can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in parentheses. These should be used in preference to using a backslash for line continuation.

> Backslashes may still be appropriate at times. For example, long, multiple with-statements cannot use implicit continuation, so backslashes are acceptable:

> ```
> with open('/path/to/some/file/you/want/to/read') as file_1, \
>      open('/path/to/some/file/being/written', 'w') as file_2:
>      file_2.write(file_1.read())
> ```
>
> Another such case is with assert statements.

> Make sure to indent the continued line appropriately. The preferred place to break around a binary operator is **after** the operator, not before it. Some examples:

> ```
> class Rectangle(Blob):
>
>   def __init__(self, width, height,
>                 color='black', emphasis=None, highlight=0):
>        if (width == 0 and height == 0 and
>           color == 'red' and emphasis == 'strong' or
>            highlight > 100):
>            raise ValueError("sorry, you lose")
>        if width == 0 and height == 0 and (color == 'red' or
>                                           emphasis is None):
>            raise ValueError("I don't think so -- values are %s, %s" %
>                             (width, height))
>        Blob.__init__(self, width, height,
>                      color, emphasis, highlight)file_2.write(file_1.read())
> ```

PEP8 now recommends the *opposite convention* (for breaking at binary operations) used by mathematicians and their publishers to improve readability.

Donald Knuth's style of breaking **before** a binary operator aligns operators vertically, thus reducing the eye's workload when determining which items are added and subtracted.

From [PEP8: *Should a line break before or after a binary operator?*](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#should-a-line-break-before-or-after-a-binary-operator):

> Donald Knuth explains the traditional rule in his Computers and Typesetting series: "Although formulas within a paragraph always break after binary operations and relations, displayed formulas always break before binary operations"[3].

> Following the tradition from mathematics usually results in more readable code:

> ```
> # Yes: easy to match operators with operands
> ```

```
income = (gross_wages
          + taxable_interest
          + (dividends - qualified_dividends)
          - ira_deduction
          - student_loan_interest)
```

> In Python code, it is permissible to break before or after a binary operator, as long as the convention is consistent locally. For new code Knuth's style is suggested.

[3]: Donald Knuth's The TeXBook, pages 195 and 196

Comment: NB the recommendation changed in 2010: "Long lines can be broken ...  by wrapping expressions in parentheses. These should be used in preference to using a backslash...", and all backslashes were removed from the code example.

Comment: @e100: read the text in bold above: `The preferred way .. is by using Python's implied line continuation inside parentheses` it is the same thing as `by wrapping expressions in parentheses`. I've updated example

Comment: But note that "sometimes using a backslash looks better" has gone too.

Comment: @e100: here're [three](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26435241/4279) [code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26399211/4279) [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26370717/4279) where backslashes make the code more readable: [*"sometimes the style guide just doesn't apply. When in doubt, use your best judgment."*](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds)

Comment: In 2015 the style guide was updated to actually prefer breaking **before** binary operators after research by [Donald Knuth](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2016-April/144205.html) due to the perceived improvements in readability.

Answer (score 89):

The danger in using a backslash to end a line is that if whitespace is added after the backslash (which, of course, is very hard to see), the backslash is no longer doing what you thought it was.

See Python Idioms and Anti-Idioms (for [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/doanddont.html#using-backslash-to-continue-statements) or [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.1/howto/doanddont.html#using-backslash-to-continue-statements)) for more.

Comment: This is one reason that it's nice to be able to see trailing whitespace better; i.e. something like `set list listchars=trail:·` in vim. :)

Comment: It is not only true for the space after the backslash. backslash should be strictly the last character in the line. In particular you cannot comment specific terms in a sum by breaking the line with backslash and putting a comment after it. Brackets work fine! :)

Comment: It is a pity that this explanation disappeared from the documentation (after 3.1). In PEP8 the reasoning is not explained.

Comment: "the backslash is no longer doing what you thought it was." - it doesn't silently do the wrong thing; it's explicitly a `SyntaxError`.

Answer (score 41):

Put a `\` at the end of your line or enclose the statement in parens `( .. )`. From [IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-python5/):

```
b = ((i1 < 20) and
     (i2 < 30) and
     (i3 < 40))
```

or

```
b = (i1 < 20) and \
    (i2 < 30) and \
    (i3 < 40)
```

Answer (score 30):

You can break lines in between parenthesises and braces. Additionally, you can append the backslash character `\` to a line to explicitly break it:

```
x = (tuples_first_value,
     second_value)
y = 1 + \
    2
```

Answer (score 27):

> From the horse's mouth: [Explicit line
>   joining](https://docs.python.org/2.5/ref/explicit-joining.html)
>
> Two or more physical lines may be
>   joined into logical lines using
>   backslash characters (`\`), as follows:
>   when a physical line ends in a
>   backslash that is not part of a string
>   literal or comment, it is joined with
>   the following forming a single logical
>   line, deleting the backslash and the
>   following end-of-line character. For
>   example:
>
> ```
> if 1900 < year < 2100 and 1 <= month <= 12 \
>    and 1 <= day <= 31 and 0 <= hour < 24 \
>    and 0 <= minute < 60 and 0 <= second < 60:   # Looks like a valid date
>         return 1
> ```
>
> A line ending in a backslash cannot
>   carry a comment. A backslash does not
>   continue a comment. A backslash does
>   not continue a token except for string
>   literals (i.e., tokens other than
>   string literals cannot be split across
>   physical lines using a backslash). A
>   backslash is illegal elsewhere on a
>   line outside a string literal.

Comment: -1 because the example is unidiomatic IMO. Compound conditionals can absolutely have enclosing brackets instead, which is more practical (for editing or automatic rewrapping) and idiomatic.

Answer (score 25):

If you want to break your line because of a long literal string, you can break that string into pieces:

```
long_string = "a very long string"
print("a very long string")
```

will be replaced by

```
long_string = (
  "a "
  "very "
  "long "
  "string"
)
print(
  "a "
  "very "
  "long "
  "string"
)
```

Output for both print statements:

`a very long string`

Notice the parenthesis in the affectation.

Notice also that breaking literal strings into pieces allows to use the literal prefix only on parts of the string and mix the delimiters:

```
s = (
  '''2+2='''
  f"{2+2}"
)
```

Answer (score 14):

One can also break the call of methods (`obj.method()`) in multiple lines.

Enclose the command in parenthesis "`()`" and span multiple lines:

```
> res = (some_object
         .apply(args)
         .filter()
         .values)
```

For instance, I find it useful on chain calling Pandas/Holoviews objects methods.

Comment: Thanks. This method is used in Microsoft Azure course PySpark examples

Answer (score 8):

It may not be the Pythonic way, but I generally use a list with the join function for writing a long string, like SQL queries:

```
query = " ".join([
    'SELECT * FROM "TableName"',
    'WHERE "SomeColumn1"=VALUE',
    'ORDER BY "SomeColumn2"',
    'LIMIT 5;'
])
```

Comment: Joining a list isn't necessary, and has performance overhead. Use a triple-quoted string literal

Comment: @OneCricketeer To be pedantic (and pedantism often seems a virtue here), triple quotes in Python are supposed to be used for docstrings I believe, and not for line continuation of string values. If you have some auto documenting software running on your code, it would then pick up this string literal as a docstring, so very naughty!

Answer (score 4):

Taken from The Hitchhiker's Guide to Python ([Line Continuation](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/style/#line-continuations)):

> When a logical line of code is longer than the accepted limit, you need to split it over multiple physical lines. The Python interpreter will join consecutive lines if the last character of the line is a backslash. This is helpful in some cases, but should usually be avoided because of its fragility: a white space added to the end of the line, after the backslash, will break the code and may have unexpected results.
>
> **A better solution is to use parentheses around your elements.** Left with an unclosed parenthesis on an end-of-line the Python interpreter will join the next line until the parentheses are closed. The same behaviour holds for curly and square braces.
>
> **However**, more often than not, having to split a long logical line is a sign that you are trying to do too many things at the same time, which may hinder readability.

Having that said, here's an example considering multiple imports (when exceeding [line limits, defined on PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length)), also applied to strings in general:

```
from app import (
    app, abort, make_response, redirect, render_template, request, session
)
```