# Save textarea value to JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, textarea

How to save the value of textarea to JSON?

I have a textarea; I need to save value of that text area into a js object.

Its working fine if there is no 'enter'(line break) pressed. How to save it and and retrieve it as such with linebreaks.

Save using

```
dataObject[0]["Category"][0]["Category"] = $('textarea').val();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiline strings in JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392766/multiline-strings-in-json)

Comment: what doesn't works? what means `save the value of textarea to JSON`?

Comment: line break in textarea is \n and there is no problem when saving it into json object

Comment: So far I can only see the JavaScript array. How do you create JSON of it, and what's the result and the error?

Comment: @MaVRoSCy Thanks I will refer that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Used this code to make it HTML

```
var newText = $('textarea').val(); //value
newText = newText.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />');
```

Answer (score 1):

i think this code can help you !

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var textarea = $('textarea').val();
var linebreak = textarea.split('\n');
var length = linebreak.length;
var data = [];
for ( var i = 0 ; i<length ; i++){
    data.push({ 'line': i , 'content': linebreak[i] });
    console.log(data);
}
```

});

for more test you can go here : http://jsfiddle.net/ABy4j/10/