# Parsing JSON with endline characters when receiving it from the server

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON that looks like so:

```
{
    "response": {
        "event": "Other",
        "time_opened": "2014-09-09 10:09:07",
        "time_updated": "2014-09-10 09:34:55",
        "name": "blablablablablabla",
        "current_status": "blablabla

blablablablablablablablablablablabla

blablablablablablablablabla

blablablablablablablablabla

"
    }
}
```

I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token" on JSON.parse. After research I couldn't figure out how to wrangle it. Sorry if duplicate, but I'm a little lost here.

Comment: That's not JSON. It's not even a parsing JS object.

Comment: JSONlint.com validates it without newline characters.

Comment: JSON doesn't allow you to have newline character, if you remove the newline characters from the "current_status" value it validates fine. My suggestion would be to change the server side code to return it without newlines.

Comment: You could replace the newlines with something like \\n as detailed in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392766/multiline-strings-in-json

Comment: I solved it with proper encoding serverside, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved with appropriate encoding server side.