# Right way to JSON serialize a multiline string

Tags: json

Gson serializes `{"test": "abc\ndef"}` to `{"test": "abc\ndef"}`. According to [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392766/multiline-strings-in-json), and my understanding of JSON standard, it is not a valid JSON. It needs to be `{"test": "abc\\ndef"}`. I.e the `"\n"` needs to be converted to `\\n`.

Is my understanding correct?