# Json not decoded if string contains ENTER newline

Tags: json

I have a form which has fields *name* and *description*.  When the form is submitted I store these values as a JSON object in the database.  Though when I retrieve the value from the database and try to decode it I get an error if a string value contains several lines:

```js
{
    "SMTPMailAccountID":"7",
    "IsActive":"1",
    "TemplateEmailName":"Cache Topup Alert Email Template ",
    "SystemServiceID":"2",
    "Body":"

     {-TOPUP_REQUEST_DATE-}

     {-TOPUP_RESPONSE_DATE-}

   "
}
```

when you parse this json it will give error.Could  not validate this json

Answer (score 1):

Multiline is not supported by json grammar.
An other question which can hep you: [Multiline strings in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392766/multiline-strings-in-json)