# How to include \n with python -m json.tool

Tags: python, json, shell, python-2.7, zsh

I'm trying to create a json file via shell, however, new lines are now allowed and through an error.

`Invalid control character at: line 5 column 26 (char 87)` which points to `\n`

```
echo '{
    "param1": "asdfasf",
    "param2": "asffad",
    "param3": "asdfsaf",
    "param4": "asdfasf\nasfasfas"
}' | python -m json.tool > test.json
```

Assuming I'd like to preserve new lines, how can I get this to put a json file?

**UPDATE:**

I'm thinking it has something to do with strict mode for python's json encoder/decoder.

> If strict is False (True is the default), then control characters will
>   be allowed inside strings. Control characters in this context are
>   those with character codes in the 0-31 range, including '\t' (tab),
>   '\n', '\r' and '\0'.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

How can strict mode be set to `False` from within `python -m json.tool`?

Comment: `asdfasf` has no quotes around it, otherwise it works for me

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the quotes, but it still does not work for me and outputs the same error message.

Comment: What shell are you trying this on?

Comment: same error using zsh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escaping the `\` seems to do the trick:

```
echo  '{
    "param1": "asdfasf",
    "param2": "asffad",
    "param3": "asdfsaf",
    "param4": "asdfasf\\nasfasfas"
}' | python -m json.tool > test.json
```

It creates valid json:

```
with open('/home/test.json', 'rU') as f:
    js = json.load(f)
    print(js)
    print(js["param4"])
```

Output:

```
{'param1': 'asdfasf', 'param3': 'asdfsaf', 'param2': 'asffad', 'param4': 'asdfasf\nasfasfas'}
asdfasf
asfasfas
```

Answer (score 1):

zsh is replacing `\n` with a proper carriage return. You could escape it or use heredoc style instead:

```
python -m json.tool > test.json << EOF
{
"param1": "asdfasf",
"param2": "asffad",
"param3": "asdfsaf",
"param4": "asdfasf\nasfasfas"
}
EOF
```

Comment: Again, this results in a json file with the string `\n` in the json itself.

Comment: But AFAIK and according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392766/multiline-strings-in-json, actual newlines are illegal in JSON.

Comment: For example, if you create the input JSON in a file with a proper line feed and cat that to your Python command, you'll get the same error :)

Comment: Thank you I did not realize this earlier.

Comment: Also, strict mode relates to serialising but your error will be occurring deserialisation. Using `json.load(input)` throws a similar error when it finds an actual carriage return :)