# How can I save new Date() in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

When I save a date time in MongoDB using the following format, it shows:

```
Error "Unable to parse JSON"
```

---

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("58cb759805aeeae37a56dd3d"),
  "name" : "Plutus",
  "admin" : "type 1",
  "created" : new Date()
}
```

Please help me to save a date time in Robomongo using MongoDB in the above format.

Error description in picture:

[image: Error message]

Thanks

Comment: Can you include the schema definition?

Comment: yes i have define schema definition
code below

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
// Define our site schema
var SiteSchema   = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:        String,
    admin:       String,
    created :    Date
});

// Export the Mongoose model
module.exports = mongoose.model('Site', SiteSchema);

Comment: Thanks; can you include this in the original post? And can you paste the original stacktrace? Yours has a typo that I'm sure isn't originally in the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try using `new ISODate("2017-03-17 11:59")`. I know it is a little cumbersome, but this is the only date value that is guaranteed to work across all versions of Robomongo and MongoDB.

Further reading -

1. https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/issues/614
2. https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/issues/477

Comment: Thanks
Date has been save but Like JavaScript for saving current date time. can i not use new Date()  function in Robomongo.?

Comment: I don't have access to Robomongo right now, but what version of Robomongo and MongoDB are you using? Does `Date.now()` work instead?

Comment: here is image link   of problem               https://ibb.co/mnVEva

 "mongodb": "^2.2.24",
 Robomongo 1.0.0

Comment: Can you respond to the second question as well?

Answer (score 4):

Just save this JSON

```
{"name": "whatever", "your_cool_date": "2017-03-17 11:59"}
```

it will be saved as a ISO date in the database:

```
"your_cool_date" : ISODate("2017-03-17T10:59:00Z"),
```

Comment: specific to Robomongo ( Robot3T )

Answer (score 1):

Error seems to be related the JSON syntax.

There may be a hard line break in there, try trimming the lines. Please see:

[Multiline strings in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392766/multiline-strings-in-json)

Answer (score 0):

Robomongo doesn't support that format, my suggestion you try MongoBooster..

MongoDB. Sure it will support format of new Date().

otherwise , you put inside date value like new Date("2017-03-17")

Answer (score 0):

Use shell to insert:

db.sites.insert({
  "_id" : ObjectId("58cb759805aeeae37a56dd3d"),
  "name" : "Plutus",
  "admin" : "type 1",
  "created" : new Date()
}