# What Markdown characters do I need to escape to store the text as a JSON string?

Tags: json, markdown

I just want to store the markdown text in a JSON string. Is it ok for me to simply copy the text into the string or do I have to manually escape certain characters?

I know that JSON uses certain characters for formatting and I would like to know what characters would be in conflict.

What characters do I need to escape?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you _tried_ anything? You should be able to answer your own question in fairly short order…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be fine to copy/paste. You will need to escape quotes with `\"`, tabs with `\t` and backslashes with `\\`.

Comment: [JSON doesn't support multi-line strings, so newlines will have to be converted as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392766/multiline-strings-in-json).