# React i18n break lines in JSON String

Tags: html, json, reactjs, i18next

I'm working with i18next for react https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next. I'm struggling to break lines within the string in my JSON language file.

This is what I already tried, which doesn't break a new line:

- `line: "This is a line. \n This is another line. \n Yet another line"`,
  [image]
- `line: ("This is a line."+  <br/> + "This is another line. \n Yet another line")`,
  [image]
- `line: ('This is a line. <br/> This is another line. \n Yet another line')`,
  [image]

I obviously try to make a new line after each sentence. This is how I call it:

```
<TooltipLink onClick={() => {
    this.toggleHelpTextDialog(t('test:test.line'));
}}/>
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: This entirely depends on the component. It may or may not support line breaks. Did you try to set the text directly without i18n translation?

Comment: I did set the text directly and it doesn't work either. I'm setting the text for the dialog via props. You think that might cause the problem?

Comment: Just look at this question, it may help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392766/multiline-strings-in-json

Comment: I think that should be straightforward in i18n library.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

You can do it with css `white-space: pre-line;` & `\n` in the translation text.

```js
const root = document.getElementById('root');

i18next.init({
  lng: 'en',
  resources: {
    en: {
      translation: {
        "key": "Hello world\nThis sentence should appear on the second line"
        // ----------------^ new line char
      }
    }
  }
}, function(err, t) {
  // initialized and ready to go!
  root.innerHTML = i18next.t('key');
});
```

```css
#root {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/i18next@15.0.9/dist/umd/i18next.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: In my case the json-editor BabelEdit escaped the `\n` to `\\n`

Comment: I'm not familiar with BabelEdit but line break (the one that creates when you hit Enter) is not writing `\n` in the editor but press Enter.

Comment: Works perfectly fine in 2022. Thank you

Comment: Be aware: You might not want this behavior everywhere! Just add the style `white-space: pre-line;` (or `white-space: pre;` for that matter) to the element enclosing your text.

Answer (score 5):

For those that do not want to add css code all over their React components, you can use the `Trans` component in the [`react-i18next` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-i18next).

Create a translation key-value similar to:

```json
{
  "message": "This is a line.<1/>This is another line.<1/>Yet another line"
}
```

Then, in your React component, use the `<Trans/>` component as follows

```
<Trans i18nKey="message" components={{ 1: <br /> }} />
```

The translation value will be rendered as

[image]

See https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/issues/282

Answer (score 4):

for example you write below text in JSON language file.

text:"Hello \n How are you? \n what are you doing?"

and then in return part write

```html
<div id='app'><div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<script>
      render() {
          return (
              text.split('\n').map(c => {
                  return ( <p> {c} </p>) 
                   });
                 )
               }
              

              ReactDOM.render(
                <BreakLine / >
                document.getElementById('app')
              )
</script>
```

well, when call split method, try to create list and seperate from '\n' and with method map type each of them on paragraph so can break line ;))

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Could you clarify your answer a bit please, the descriptive text is difficult to understand.

Answer (score 4):

You can add specifically to TooltipLink styles:

```
white-space: pre-line;
```

then, your \n in locale will work.

Comment: This is the best solution in my case. I'm using Tailwind CSS, so I've used `whitespace-pre-line` class.

Answer (score 1):

For me, directly using this `<br/>` inside a string worked e.g

```js
{ loremIpsum: "Lorem <br/> ipsum" }

<Trans
  i18nKey='loremIpsum'
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

For more complex cases, you could be using `<Trans />` component and any HTML tags and even create custom ones.

Example:

```
<Trans
  components={{ boldSpan: <MyTextComponent strong component="span" variant="body" /> }}
  i18nKey="YourNamespace:TEXT_KEY"
/>
```

While your JSON file (YourNamespace.json):

```
{
  "TEXT_KEY" : "<boldSpan>Lorem ipsum</boldSpan><br/>",
}
```

For more details, check here: https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component

Answer (score 0):

you can simbly use dangerouslySetInnerHTML like this

```
{"text":"first <br/> second"}
```

then

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: t('text') }}></div>
```