# How to extract react-i18next translation using function call?

Tags: i18next, react-i18next

Given the following code:

```
<Trans i18nKey="error" ns="login">
  <p className="error">
    {React.string("Incorrect username/password combination.")}
    <br />
    {React.string("Is Caps Lock turned on?")}
  </p>
</Trans>
```

Notice the `React.string` function calls.

Is there a way to make this work with i18next? What would this key's value look like in the JSON file?

### Update

In my translations JSON file, how should the above code look?

```
"error": "<1>???</1>"
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, can you add some example?

Comment: @felixmosh I've added an update. I'm looking to understand how the translations JSON value could look like, as I haven't been able to figure out a way to make the `<Trans />` implementation work with the `{React.string("...")}` part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what is this `React.string` method, but the whole purpose of `Trans` is to integrate style tags in a text.

The text should be in the translation (json) file.

Your usage should look like:

```js
<p className="error">
  <Trans i18nKey="error" ns="login" />
</p>
```

```json
{
  "error": "Incorrect username/password combination.<br />Is Caps Lock turned on?"
}
```

BTW, for line break you can avoid `Trans` component, you can use white space and css, for more info read this answer: [React i18n break lines in JSON String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45856051/react-i18n-break-lines-in-json-string#answer-54747308)

Comment: Hmm, with that JSON value, the `<p className="error">` markup is lost. Thank you for the tip for whitespace formatting.

Comment: I've tried using `"error": "<1>Incorrect username / password combination.<br />Is Caps Lock turned on?</1>"` and still the `<p>` formatting is lost. This source code does get compiled to ES5 (after the JSX trasformation -> `React.createElement(...)` conversion is already done) and I'm wondering if that is problematic here

Comment: I've also tried `"error": "<p class='error'>Incorrect username / password combination.<br />Is Caps Lock turned on?</p>"` and this keeps the `<p>` but losses the class name.

Comment: Look carefully my example, the `p` is outside of the `Trans` component, think that `Trans` is a replacement for the *text*