# Javascript tags not working in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, email, postman

I have written an API to send an email. I am using Postman for this. It is working fine with normal text. When adding the script tag in the "HTML", it's throwing the following error.

> 400 Bad Request

with the Response body

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token  
>     at Object.parse
>   (native)
>     at parse
>   (/root/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:88:17)
>   
>    at /root/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:116:18
>   
>    at invokeCallback
>   (/root/node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:262:16)
>      at done
>   (/root/node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:251:7)
>      at IncomingMessage.onEnd
>   (/root/node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:307:7)
>      at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit
>   (events.js:92:17)
>     at _stream_readable.js:920:16
>      at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:459:13)

The request body I am sending is:

```
{
    "from": "\"David Johnson\" <djohnson@gmail.com>",
    "to": "david.johnson@gmail.com",
    "subject": "Test",
    "html": "Dear David, <br /> <br /> Thanks for the mail. PFB the detailed report.
    <script src=\"https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js\"></script>
    <script src=\"https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js\"></script>

    <div id=\"container\" style=\"min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto\"></div>
    <script>
    Highcharts.chart('container',
    {
    chart: {
        type: 'areaspline'
        },
    title: {
        text: 'Bandwidth Utilization'
        },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'left',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: 150,
        y: 100,
        floating: true,
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'
        },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [
        '00: 00',
        '01: 00',
        '02: 00',
        '03: 00',
        '04: 00',
        '05: 00',
        '06: 00',
        '07: 00',
        '08: 00',
        '09: 00',
        '10: 00',
        '11: 00',
        '12: 00',
        '13: 00',
        '14: 00',
        '15: 00',
        '16: 00',
        '17: 00',
        '18: 00',
        '19: 00',
        '20: 00',
        '21: 00',
        '22: 00',
        '23: 00'
            ],
        title: {
        text: 'Hours (GMT)'
            }
        },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
        text: 'Bandwidth (Mbps)'
            }
        },
    tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        valueSuffix: ' Mbps'
        },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
        },
    plotOptions: {
        areaspline: {
        fillOpacity: 0.5
            }
        },
    series: [
            {
        name: 'India - (GMT +5.5)',
        data: [
                    3,
                    5,
                    4,
                    10,
                    12,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    3,
                    4,
                    3
                ]
            },
            {
        name: 'Ireland - (GMT +0.0)',
        data: [
                    1,
                    3,
                    4,
                    3,
                    3,
                    5,
                    4,
                    4,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0
                ]
            },
            {
        name: 'Samoa - (GMT -11.0)',
        data: [
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    3,
                    4,
                    4,
                    9,
                    15,
                    10,
                    12,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0
                ]
            }
        ]
    });
    </script>"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON didn't allow *line-breaks*

Based on the solutions in the question [multiline-strings-in-json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392766/multiline-strings-in-json) you could write everything in one line but if the line-breaks are important you could use `\n` or you wrap multiple strings into an array of strings.

It has nothing to do with the `<script>` tag because the tag is inside a string and every character inside a string is valid as long as you escape them if needed like qoutes (`\"`) or line-breaks (`\n`)

## use `\n`

```
{
    "html":"Dear David, <br /> <br /> Thanks for the mail. PFB the detailed report.\n<script src=\"https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js\"></script>\n...
}
```

## use an array as wrapper

```
"html": [
    "Dear David, <br /> <br /> Thanks for the mail. PFB the detailed report.",
    "<script src=\"https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js\"></script>",
    "<script src=\"https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js\"></script>",

    "<div id=\"container\" style=\"min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto\"></div>",
    "<script>",
    "Highcharts.chart('container', {",
    "chart: {"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

As far i see the request its ok it just you might have missed the model property in your to be set with [AllowHtml] header.

Pls reffer this see if it works:
eg:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
  [AllowHtml]
  public string SomeHtmlProperty { get; set; }
}
```