# Line continuations in CMakeSettings json files

Tags: json, cmake, visual-studio-2017

Is there a way to split an element's argument across multiple lines. For example, in the image below if I wanted to add a couple of line breaks to `buildRoot`'s argument, it might look like this:

```
"buildRoot": "${env.USERPROFILE}\\CMakeBuilds\\"
             "${workspaceHash}\\build\\"
             "${name}",
```

Is, there a valid way to do this?

[image: json image]
[Image reference](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2018/06/27/cmake-support-in-visual-studio-configuration-templates/)

I don't know if it matters (this might just be a json thing), but I'm using

**Visual Studio 2017**

Comment: Related, maybe a duplicate except that VS might have an extension to json which allow this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2392766/1896169

Comment: @Justin Thanks for the link. I can’t find any similar mechanism for VS, but at least it confirms that I’m not overlooking some simple json syntax.