# Multi line Json string

Tags: json

I am having a json file which is having very long string. I want to break the string into multi line to increase the readability.

```
{
"messages" : {
  "u": {
    "14" :
      "One|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne|One"
    ,
    "2":
      "Version|one|two|three"

  }
}
```

}

Can I break the above string into multi line?

Comment: as long as the quotes are not broken, JSON doesn't care about multi-lines

Comment: @Satya: Did not get that

Comment: just keep the quotes intact when breaking string across the line. You should be fine.

Comment: @Satya: Not working. I tried breaking the string by pressing enter it gives error as expected , but got nothing

Comment: If it gives you an error, please add it. Also add your code in which you tried to multi-line the string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiline strings in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392766/multiline-strings-in-json)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to deal with it is to make an array of strings, and when you get them, just use `[].join('')`. Your code should look something like this:

```js
{
  "messages": {
    "u": {
      "2": [
        "Version|one",
        "|two|three"
      ],
      "14": [
        "One|OneOne|OneOne",
        "|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne",
        "|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne",
        "|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne",
        "|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne",
        "|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne",
        "|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne",
        "|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne",
        "|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne",
        "|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne",
        "|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne",
        "|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne",
        "|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne",
        "|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne",
        "|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne",
        "|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne",
        "|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne",
        "|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne",
        "|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne",
        "|OneOne|OneOne|OneOne",
        "|OneOne|OneOne|One"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And than in your JS file:

```js
let longString = yourJSONObject['14'].join('')
```