# How to read JSON's credentials from code (string)

Tags: python, json, google-oauth

I have a JSON file from google spreadsheet (for reading the spreadsheet).

I'm trying to copy the JSON as a string to the script.

this is how I do it :

```
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import gspread

   json_string ='''
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "ID",
  "private_key_id": "KEYID",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----

 ......KEY HERE......

  -----END PRIVATE KEY-----
  ",
  "client_email": "EMAIL",
  "client_id": "ID",
  "auth_uri": "URI",
  "token_uri": "URI",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "URL",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "CLINET"
}
  '''

info = json.loads(json_string.replace("'",'"').replace('\r\n', '\\r\\n'), strict=False)
client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
sheet = client.open("Responses").sheet1
...


ERROR OUTPUT -


      private_key_pkcs8_pem = json_data['_private_key_pkcs8_pem']
KeyError: '_private_key_pkcs8_pem'
```

Any suggestions for how to read the string as JSON credentials correctly?

Comment: your code does not show what `json_data` is or where it comes from. The `json_string`  which you load into `info` has no key `_private_key_pkcs8_pem` indeed. the key is `private_key`

Comment: @buran I don't think I understand you, I have a `private_key` It's long so I didn't put it in my question. And about `_private_key_pkcs8_pem ` I don't have it on my JSON file from google, so what should I do?

Comment: the error message refers to this line of code `private_key_pkcs8_pem = json_data['_private_key_pkcs8_pem']` - we don't see it in your code. Nor we see what `json_data` is or where it comes from. Also the error message says key `_private_key_pkcs8_pem` is missing. Note that it does not raise `NameError` for `json_data`, so `json_data` IS defined somewhere else in your code. We also don't see what `credentials` is. Finally you should post the full traceback. Read [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea, not sure if it's the correct response to your question: **You cannot you classic line breaks in JSON.** Probably, your private key (or another property you did not include in your code example) contains line breaks and thus the JSON string is invalid.

Read also [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392766/multiline-strings-in-json) for more information on how to use line breaks in JSON documents.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_dict` and not `ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json`.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, initializing credentials from a string, since we use a remote python client and uploading credential files was not easy.

```
SCOPES = ('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform')
json_data = """{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "xxxxxxxx",
  "private_key_id": "xxxxxxxxxx",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----xxxxxxxx",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robotxxxxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}"""
json_key = js.loads(json_data,strict=False)
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(json_key,scopes=SCOPES)

my_client_py = pg.authorize(custom_credentials=credentials)
```