# Adding next line in a large json string from Jersey, Rest API

Tags: java, json, jersey, swagger, jersey-2.0

I want to split a very large string into multiple lines. When I use next line characters, those characters are displayed in Swagger UI without having multiple lines.

Code is as below:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;


@Path("test")
@Api(tags = {"Testing"})
public class TestingService {

@Context
private HttpServletRequest request;

@GET
@Path("testing")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@ApiOperation(value = "Testing",
response = String.class)    
public String getString(
         throws Exception {
    return "abcdef,fghijk";
}
}
```

Input is:

```
abcdef,fghijk
```

```
Current Output:
{

  "messages": "abcdef,fghijk"
}

Expected Output:    
{

  "messages": "abcdef,
              fghijk"
}
```

I have tried `\n`, `\\n`, `\\\n` and `\r\n`.

Note: I am using Jersey Framework for this REST API & Swagger for UI.

Thanks a lot in advance for the help.

Comment: Some code could be useful.

Comment: Is `"abcdef,fghijk"` a String or do you actually mean to use a list like `[abcdef,fghijk]`?

Comment: "abcdef,fghijk" : This is string. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392766/multiline-strings-in-json has some answers

Comment: looks like, this is not possible to do. Thanks @Smile.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround : 
(a) split the string on some basis 
(b) create a list of object where object stores the split string. 
(c)Send the list to UI as response.

Output will be as below:

```
{

  "messages_list": [
                    {"message": "abcdef"},
                    {"message": "fghijk"}
                   ]
}
```

Note: This was not the actual requirement. This is just workaround to display long & different messages in different lines.