# Google chat: Invalid JSON payload received. Closing quote expected in string.\n\n^

Tags: json, bash, google-chat

I am trying to send a google chat message using bash script. When I define a local variable or using simple text, it works. But when I source a file, and use variables defined in that file, I get error.

**This works:**

```
#!/bin/bash
MSG="Data"
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST "$CHAT_URL" --data @<(cat <<EOF
{
  "cards": [
    {
      "sections": [
        {
          "widgets": [
            {
                "textParagraph": {
                    "text": "Msg: $MSG"
                }
            }]}]}]}
EOF
)
```

**This does not:**

```
#!/bin/bash
source file.txt      # contents: MSG=Data
echo $MSG            # variable defined in file.txt
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST "$CHAT_URL" --data @<(cat <<EOF
{
  "cards": [
    {
      "sections": [
        {
          "widgets": [
            {
                "textParagraph": {
                    "text": "Msg: $MSG"
                }
            }]}]}]}
EOF
)
```

**Output:**

```
Data
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Closing quote expected in string.\n\n^",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is basically a duplicate of
[Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings)
and
[Are multi-line strings allowed in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2392766/6770384)

Your file has windows line endings (`\r\n`). Therefore the string loaded from your file ends with `\r`. JSON strings are not allowed to contain control characters, hence the error message.

To fix the problem, convert your file using `dos2unix file.txt`.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Bundles of thanks. 
Btw I used `tr -d '\r' < file.txt >unix.txt` because I prefer OS utilities.