# JSON neglect { when POST

Tags: javascript, json, postman, bigcommerce

I need to POST a script by using BigCommerce API.
Here is the body

```
{
  "name": "string",
  "description": "string",
  "html": "string",
  "src": "(function (sCDN, sCDNProject, sCDNWorkspace, sCDNVers) {
    if (
      window.localStorage !== null &&
      typeof window.localStorage === 'object' &&
      typeof window.localStorage.getItem === 'function' &&
      window.sessionStorage !== null &&
      typeof window.sessionStorage === 'object' &&
      typeof window.sessionStorage.getItem === 'function'
    ) {
      sCDNVers =
        window.sessionStorage.getItem('wx_preview_version') ||
        window.localStorage.getItem('wx_preview_version') ||
        sCDNVers;
    }
    window.x= window.x|| {};
    window.x.config = window.x.config || {};
    window.x.config.frontend = window.x.config.frontend || {};
    window.x.config.frontend.cdnhost =
      sCDN + '/get/' + sCDNWorkspace + '/web/' + sCDNVers + '/';
    window.x.config.frontend.vers = sCDNVers;
    window.x.config.frontend.env = sCDNWorkspace;
    window.x.config.frontend.project = sCDNProject;
    window._wx = window._wx || [];
    var f = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    var j = document.createElement('script');
    j.async = true;
    j.src = window.x.config.frontend.cdnhost + 'sss.js';
    f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
  })(
    'https://xxxx.x-x-x.mybigcommerce.com',
    'x-test-env',
    'live',
    '_'
  );",
  "auto_uninstall": true,
  "load_method": "default",
  "location": "head",
  "visibility": "storefront",
  "kind": "src",
  "api_client_id": "string",
  "consent_category": "essential",
  "enabled": true,
  "channel_id": 1
}
```

but it returned

> {
> "status": 400,
> "title": "Input is invalid",
> "type": "https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/getting-started/api-status-codes",
> "errors": {} }

Seems like it occurred with '{'
[image]

Any method that I can POST this script to head?

Comment: Escape those characters in the string by replacing `{` with `\{`.

Comment: Strings in JSON can't have literal newlines. Where does that JSON come from? You probably want to use a better JSON serializer to generate the JSON.

Comment: @HereticMonkey: JSON shouldn't require escaping the `{`. New lines seem to be the problem here.

Comment: You have new lines in your JSON? That is not valid.

Comment: This may be best explained by: [Are multi-line strings allowed in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392766/are-multi-line-strings-allowed-in-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe src should be a URL to a script file.

If you want to embed JavaScript then place it in the HTML field and wrap a  tag around it.

Comment: Yeah, It worked after adding `"html" : "<script>Blaa blaa</script>"`. And also I added to one line.

Answer (score 1):

Make the script one lined. JSON is broken because of new line.

Comment: Can you please clarify whether you are recommending modifying the JavaScript to no longer have line breaks at all (which I do not suggest, but that's what people typically mean by having a script be "one-lined"), or if you are recommending encoding the text of the JavaScript properly into JSON value format by representing newline characters as `\n` as required by JSON? i.e. like  `"src": "function() {\n}"`

Comment: "src": "should be one lined here" -> this will work. "src": "if i put linebreak here it will be broken". In "src" value you should use one line. On attached screenshot author has line break inside of JSON body. It is not valid syntax for JSON. Only way to transfer this script is to make it one lined.

Comment: I'm saying "one-lined" is not a good description of the solution.  Replacing line breaks with `\n` is a better description of how to fix the problem.