# How can I split in different lines a single one line in JSON

Tags: json

I want to split this line in diffent one because is too long and is difficult to read

"command": "source ~/watchman-zephyr-3.2.0/.venv/bin/activate ; west build -b nrf52840_wfinger_v1 --build-dir build_bootloader ../../../bootloader/mcuboot/boot/zephyr ; west build -p auto -b nrf52840_wfinger_v1 --build-dir build",

I tried the next but seems is wrong:
"command": "source ~/watchman-zephyr-3.2.0/.venv/bin/activate ; 
west build -b nrf52840_wfinger_v1 --build-dir build_bootloader ../../../bootloader/mcuboot/boot/zephyr ; 
west build -p auto -b nrf52840_wfinger_v1 --build-dir build",

Comment: JSON doesn't allow line breaks for readability. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392766/are-multi-line-strings-allowed-in-json).