# how to break line in GITHUB actions yaml file correctly?

Tags: yaml, github-actions

I sucked and do not know how to break line "text" correctly,
here is the snipped of workflow file:

```
raw: >-
            {
              "@type": "MessageCard",
              "@context": "http://schema.org/extensions",
              "title": "Smoke test run on ${{ env.AOS_TEST_ENV }}",
              "text": "Status: **${{ env.RESULTS }}**\n\n---\n\n[GitHub link](${{ env.GITHUB_URL }})\n\n---\n\n[TestRail link](${{ env.TR_RUN_URL }})\n\n---\n\n**Project-version: ${{ env.PROJECT }}**",
              "themeColor": "00FF00"
            }
```

the linter (yamllint) reporting an error:
156:121   error    line too long (195 > 120 characters)  (line-length)

i have tried break "line" into two: "line1"+ "line2", "line1 \ line2"

Answer (score 0):

JSON doesn't support concatenations nor embedded newlines in a string literal. So there is now ay in the current way you have configured the item to solve your YAML ling warning.

My suggestion is to turn off the lint rule for the (pretty short) max line length.

If that's not an option, you'll have to build that JSON blob in a different way, something like this:

```yaml
    steps:
      - run: |
          $messagecard = [ordered]@{}
          $messagecard["@type"] = "MessageCard"
          $messagecard["@context"] = "http://schema.org/extensions"
          $messagecard["title"] = "Smoke test run on $env:AOS_TEST_ENV"
          $messagecard["text"] = "Status: **$env:RESULTS**
          
          ---
          
          [GitHub link]($env:GITHUB_URL)
          
          ---
          
          [TestRail link]($env:TR_RUN_URL)
          
          ---
          
          **Project-version: $env:PROJECT**"
          $messagecard["themeColor"] = "00FF00"
      
          echo "message-card<<EOF" >> $env:GITHUB_OUTPUT
          echo (convertto-json $messagecard) >> $env:GITHUB_OUTPUT
          echo "EOF" >> $env:GITHUB_OUTPUT
      
        shell: pwsh
        id: set-template
      
      - uses: skitionek/notify-microsoft-teams@v1.0.8
        with: 
          webhook_url: ${{ secrets.MSTEAMS_SMOKE_WEBHOOK }} 
          needs: ${{ toJson(needs) }}
          job: ${{ toJson(job) }}
          steps: ${{ toJson(steps) }}
          raw: ${{ steps.set-template.outputs.message-card }}
```

By using PowerShell to build the json you prevent a few injection and encoding issues as well. You could do something similar with `jq` in bash probably.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help.

Comment: How did it not help?

Comment: Gihub actions warns an error of parsing JSON.....

Comment: GitHub isn't, it must be the action you're passing the json to. Can you share more context of the action you're using? have you tried moving the contents to a file?

Comment: But the json standard doesn't support concatenation, so there's no way to keep your json data in the YAML and not cause the line to grow beyond the yaml linter rules you've configured. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392766/are-multi-line-strings-allowed-in-json

Comment: - name: 
        uses: skitionek/notify-microsoft-teams@master
        with:
          webhook_url: ${{ secrets.MSTEAMS_SMOKE_WEBHOOK }}
          needs: 
          job: 
          steps:
          raw: |
              {
                "@type": ,
                "@context":,
                "title": "title",
                "text": "Status: **${{ env.RESULTS }}**\n\n---\n\n[GitHub link](${{ env.GITHUB_URL }})\n\n---\n\n[TestRail link](${{ env.TR_RUN_URL }})\n\n---\n\n**Project-version: ${{ env.PROJECT }}**"}