# "\n" in std::string is printed as "\n" itself when writing to a JSON file using RapidJSON

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

I have a JSON string with `\n` characters in the middle. When I use `cout` to test printing the string, below is the output I get, which is expected.

I am constructing the string with something like this:

```cpp
string jsonStr = "{\n Enable : ";
jsonStr += "1\n";
jsonStr += "test : ";
jsonStr += "hello\n";
jsonStr += "}\n";
```

I print the `jsonStr` with `cout << jsonStr`, and it prints the string as expected:

```
{
    Enable  : 1
    test : hello
}
```

But when I try to write this string to a JSON file using pretty writer, it adds the `\n` as well to the JSON member values.

I can't figure out how to get rid of this `\n`. In my Google searching, I found some solution to try appending `\\n` instead of `\n` to the string, but it still didn't work. The JSON file had `\\n` added to the string instead of `\n`.

How can I fix this?

Below is the code I've tried:

```cpp
void write_to_module_json_file(const string jsonStr, const string moduleName) {

    string jsonFile = getConfigName(moduleName)+".json";

    Document d(kObjectType);
    Value data(kObjectType);
    Value value;
    value.SetString(jsonStr.c_str(), d.GetAllocator());
    data.AddMember(rapidjson::StringRef(getConfigName(moduleName).c_str()), value,d.GetAllocator());
    d.AddMember("config", data, d.GetAllocator());

    FILE* fp = fopen(jsonFile.c_str(), "wb"); 
    char writeBuffer[65536];
    FileWriteStream os(fp, writeBuffer, sizeof(writeBuffer));

    PrettyWriter<FileWriteStream> writer(os);
    writer.SetIndent('\t',1);
    d.Accept(writer);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

The JSON file has the below content:

```json
{
    "config": {
        "xxx": "{\n    Enable  : 1\n    test : hello\n}\n"
    }
}
```

My expectation is to have the JSON file content as:

```json
{
    "config": 
     {
        "xxx": 
        {
            Enable  : 1,
            test : hello
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your expected JSON is not valid JSON, so you will not be able to get such output with a proper JSON writer such as `rapidjson`.

Comment: rapidjson is doing the right thing, you can't have multi-line strings in json: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392766/are-multi-line-strings-allowed-in-json

Comment: Your jsonStr doesn't contain valid JSON, because it's missing quotes around object keys and strings. But that doesn't matter to RapidJSON, because you're telling it to add jsonStr as a string value, not a JSON snippet.

Comment: As an aside, `getConfigName(moduleName).c_str()` is just begging to be a dangling reference.

Comment: @SebastianRedl it is also missing a comma between the two fields. In any case, your comment should be posted as an answer instead

Answer (score 0):

Per comments:

> Your jsonStr doesn't contain valid JSON, because it's missing quotes around object keys and strings. **But that doesn't matter to RapidJSON, because you're telling it to add jsonStr as a string value, not a JSON snippet.**
>
> – [Sebastian Redl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77668066/77668973#comment136926665_77668066)

> it is also **missing a comma** between the two fields.
>
> – [Remy Lebeau](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77668066/77668973#comment136927450_77668066)

Your `jsonStr` content is malformed as JSON, but that doesn't matter since you are assigning the content of `jsonStr` as-is as a single string value `xxx` in your final JSON document.  But the C++ `'\n'` character is not allowed to appear as-is in a JSON string value, a JSON string value cannot span multiple lines.

That is why the `'\n'` character in your `std::string` gets *escaped* as `"\n"` in the final JSON.

To get the JSON result you are looking for, you need to *parse* your `jsonStr` as its own JSON value first, and then add that value to your final document, eg:

```cpp
// NOTE THE EXTRA QUOTES AND COMMA TO MAKE THIS LEGAL JSON...
string jsonStr = "{\n \"Enable\" : ";
jsonStr += "1,\n";
jsonStr += "\"test\" : ";
jsonStr += "\"hello\"\n";
jsonStr += "}\n";
```

```cpp
void write_to_module_json_file(const string jsonStr, const string moduleName) {

    string configName = getConfigName(moduleName);
    string jsonFile = configName + ".json";

    Document d(kObjectType);
    Value data(kObjectType);

    /* DON'T DO THIS!!!
    Value value;
    value.SetString(jsonStr.c_str(), d.GetAllocator());
    data.AddMember(configName.c_str(), value, d.GetAllocator());
    */
    // DO THIS INSTEAD...
    Document doc;
    doc.Parse(jsonStr.c_str());
    data.AddMember(configName.c_str(), doc, d.GetAllocator());
    //

    d.AddMember("config", data, d.GetAllocator());

    FILE* fp = fopen(jsonFile.c_str(), "wb"); 
    char writeBuffer[65536];
    FileWriteStream os(fp, writeBuffer, sizeof(writeBuffer));

    PrettyWriter<FileWriteStream> writer(os);
    writer.SetIndent('\t',1);
    d.Accept(writer);
    fclose(fp);
}
```