# Correct way to put long function calls on multiple lines

Tags: python, multiline

I have a long function, as seen below:

```
hash_correct = hashlib.md5(salt + password)).digest().encode("base64")
```

I'd like to split it up into two lines but am not sure of the correct way to do this in Python?

Thanks.

Comment: dup:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53162/how-can-i-do-a-line-break-line-continuation-in-python

Comment: This question is different from the one you referenced as it is not a long string.

Comment: @ensnare:  the same rules apply.  The accepted answer to that question lists all possible ways to break up a long line in Python.

Comment: btw, you have an extra closing paren after `password`

Comment: I disagree.  This is a question about clarity, not syntax.

Comment: @Charles: fair point; +1 to your answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The coding guidelines limiting length of lines is there, in part, to make the code more readable.   In your case of chained method calls, the meaning is not clear.  You should pick some temporary variable names for the intermediate values so that a reader of the code can understand the chain easily.

One example might be:

```
safe_md5 = hashlib.md5(salt + password)
crypto_hash = safe_md5.digest()
hash_correct = crypto_hash.encode('base64')
```

This leads the reader down a garden path to understanding.  Very little is lost in performance, and the additional code is all added for purpose.

Comment: I think you're missing an invocation on the `.digest` function, but other than that, very good answer.

Comment: little lost in *runtime* performance, maybe but not having any scope operator all those intermediate variables will live for the duration of the function, if they happen to need large memory, all the worse.

Answer (score 3):

Prefer Charles Merram's answer, but I thought this worth noting as working but ugly and to be discouraged. Because '.' is a lexical [delimiter](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#delimiters), the following worked:

```
>>> 'abc def' . split()
['abc', 'def']
>>> 'abc def' . \
... split()
['abc', 'def']
>>> sys.version
'2.6.4 (r264:75706, Dec  7 2009, 18:45:15) \n[GCC 4.4.1]'
```

but don't do that.