# Python3.2 vertical chaining

Tags: python, syntax, python-3.x

In Python3.2 I can do this:

```
foo = Bar()
foo.setSomething(something1).setStatus('horizontal').setAttributes(attributes)
```

Eventually the chain becomes pretty long. I have an itch for a vertical chaining.

```
foo = Bar()
foo.setSomething(something1)
   .setStatus('vertical')
   .setAttributes(attributes)
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550439/correct-way-to-put-long-function-calls-on-multiple-lines

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53162/how-can-i-do-a-line-break-line-continuation-in-python

Comment: Thank you guys for links. Could not find any of these questions since I was looking by keyword "chaining" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just enclose your expression in parenthesis:

```
foo = Bar()
(foo.setSomething(something1)
     .setStatus('vertical')
     .setAttributes(attributes))
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you @Krotton for the answer it works indeed. Also thanks to @sean for the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550439/correct-way-to-put-long-function-calls-on-multiple-lines). So, the correct way to use vertical chaining is:

```
foo = Bar()
(foo.setSomething(something1)
     .setStatus('vertical')
     .setAttributes(attributes))
```

You also may use the syntax, like with multi-line strings, to allow vertical chaining:

```
foo = Bar()
foo.setSomething(something1)\
   .setStatus('vertical')\
   .setAttributes(attributes)
```