# "assert" statement with or without parentheses

Tags: python, assert, parentheses, pep8, statements

Here are four simple invocations of assert:

```
>>> assert 1==2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
AssertionError

>>> assert 1==2, "hi"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
AssertionError: hi

>>> assert(1==2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
AssertionError

>>> assert(1==2, "hi")
```

Note that the last one does not raise an error.  What is the difference between calling assert with or without parenthesis that causes this behavior?  My practice is to use parenthesis, but the above suggests that I should not.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answers.  The distinction between keywords and built-in functions seems subtle.  Here is a list of keywords, for which I presume, parens should be left out: http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords

Comment: One difference is that you can redefine built-in functions but can't do so with keywords (not that the former is a good idea).

Comment: It's not function vs keyword distinction, but *function call* vs *statement*. (for example - print used to be a statement, and worked without parentheses).

Answer (score 163, accepted):

The last `assert` would have given you a warning (`SyntaxWarning: assertion is always true, perhaps remove parentheses?`) if you ran it through a full interpreter, not through IDLE.  Because `assert` is a keyword and not a function, you are actually passing in a tuple as the first argument and leaving off the second argument.

Recall that non-empty tuples evaluate to `True`, and since the assertion message is optional, you've essentially called `assert True` when you wrote `assert(1==2, "hi")`.

Comment: The reason is doesn't happen for `assert (1==2)` is parentheses around a single expression won't create a tuple automatically; you'd get the same behavior as #4 if you did `assert (1==2,)`. The same thing would happen if you did `print ('foo', 'bar')` instead of `print 'foo', 'bar'`; you'd see the tuple outputted

Comment: It's worth further emphasizing that statements of the form `assert(test, message)` probably wrong, and certainly confusing.  No parens!

Comment: So, what is the proper way to indent a long assert statement, w.r.t. PEP8? Seems impossible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16065482/how-to-format-a-python-assert-statement-that-complies-with-pep8

Answer (score 56):

If you put the parenthesis in there because you wanted a multi-line assert, then an alternative is to put a backslash at the end of the line like this:

```
foo = 7
assert foo == 8, \
    "derp should be 8, it is " + str(foo)
```

Prints:

```
AssertionError: "derp should be 8, it is 7
```

### Why does this python `assert` have to be different from everything else:

I think the pythonic ideology is that a program should self-correct without having to worry about the special flag to turn on asserts.  The temptation to turn off asserts is too great, and thus it's being deprecated.

I share your annoyance that the python `assert` has unique syntax relative to all other python programming constructs, and this syntax has yet again changed from python2 to python3 and again changed from python 3.4 to 3.6. 
 Making assert statements not backward compatible from any version to any other version.

It's a tap on the shoulder that `assert` is a 3rd class citizen, it will be totally removed in python4, and certainly again in Python 8.1.

Comment: Is there doc on what we should use instead of assert? Assert seems like such a logical name for validating, and it has the behavior desired, eg show a special message upon error.

Comment: I lol'ed at assert being removed *again* in Python 8.1

Comment: @YPOC The original writers of these codons selecting monty python's "The cheese shop" sketch, were giving the properly initiated everything they needed to know about their plans on how to solve the naming problem in computer science as described by knuth/richie.

Answer (score 36):

You can break assert statement without `\` like this:

```
foo = 7
assert foo == 8, (
    'derp should be 8, it is ' + str(foo))
```

Or if you have even longer message:

```
foo = 7
assert foo == 8, (
    'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting '
    'industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text '
    'ever since the 1500s'
)
```

Comment: Interesting idea. I hate backslashes for continuation, and this is an alternative to wrapping assert in a utility function (which was my solution).

Answer (score 21):

`assert 1==2, "hi"` is parsed as `assert 1==2, "hi"` with "hi" as the second parameter for the keyword. Hence why it properly gives an error.

`assert(1==2)` is parsed as `assert (1==2)` which is identical to `assert 1==2`, because parens around a single item don't create a tuple unless there's a trailing comma e.g. `(1==2,)`.

`assert(1==2, "hi")` is parsed as `assert (1==2, "hi")`, which doesn't give an error because a non-empty tuple `(False, "hi")` isn't a false value, and there is no second parameter supplied to the keyword.

You shouldn't use parentheses because `assert` is not a function in Python - it's a keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Following is cited from the [python doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=assert#grammar-token-assert_stmt)

> Assert statements are a convenient way to insert debugging assertions into a program:
>
> `assert_stmt ::=  "assert" expression ["," expression]`

The simple form, assert expression, is equivalent to

`if __debug__:
    if not expression: raise AssertionError`

*The extended form, assert expression1, expression2*, is equivalent to

`if __debug__:
    if not expression1: raise AssertionError(expression2)`

So when you're using parenthesis here, you're using the simple form, and *the expression is evaluated as a tuple, which is always True when being casted to bool*

Answer (score 0):

**[assert](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement) statement** with or without **parentheses** as shown below are the same:

```py
assert (x == 3)
```

```py
assert x == 3
```

---

And, **other statements** such as [**if**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-if-statement), [**while**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-while-statement), [**for**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) and [**del**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-del-statement) with or without **parentheses** as shown below are also the same:

---

```py
if (x == "Hello"):
```

```py
if x == "Hello":
```

---

```py
while (x == 3):
```

```py
while x == 3:
```

---

```py
for (x) in (fruits):
```

```py
for x in fruits:
```

---

---

```py
del (x)
```

```py
del x
```

---

In addition, basically, most example python code which I've seen so far doesn't use **parentheses** for `assert`, `if`, `while`, `for` and  `del` statements so I prefer not using **parentheses** for them.