# How to format a python assert statement that complies with PEP8?

Tags: python, assert, pep8

How does one format a long assert statement that complies with PEP8? Please ignore the contrived nature of my example.

```
def afunc(some_param_name):
    assert isinstance(some_param_name, SomeClassName), 'some_param_name must be an instance of SomeClassName, silly goose!'
```

One cannot wrap it in parenthesis, because that changes the behavior of the assert statement since it is a keyword, not a builtin function.

Comment: `assert` should really only be used for **debugging** purpose, any other use is abuse of the `assert` functionality. All `assert`s are also removed when running python with the `-O` option.

Comment: @Wessie I don't see how that is relevant.

Comment: Besides @Wessie, [assert has many uses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18980471/673991). It can inform human readers of the code as to features, intentions, limitations, expectations. It has a place in healthy, styled, production code.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

It's important to remember that PEP8 is only a guideline and [even states that there are times when the rules *should* be broken](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds).

> But most importantly: know when to be inconsistent -- sometimes the style guide just doesn't apply.

With that in mind, I would probably write this with old style line continuation:

```
def afunc(some_param_name):
    assert isinstance(some_param_name, SomeClassName), \ 
           'some_param_name must be an instance of SomeClassName, silly goose!'
```

If that doesn't sit well with you (or your linter), you can always do:

```
def afunc(some_param_name):
    assert isinstance(some_param_name, SomeClassName), ( 
           'some_param_name must be an instance of SomeClassName, silly goose!')
```

or even:

```
def afunc(some_param_name):
    assert isinstance(some_param_name, SomeClassName), ( 
           'some_param_name must be an instance of SomeClassName, '
           'silly goose!')
```

Comment: +1. I would argue this is the more readable solution here. Bracket continuations are *preferred* over backslash line continuations, but that's a general statement, and individual cases vary.

Comment: +1 for "rules should be broken". I tend to use the old style line continuation, if only because it's the solution which requires the fewest keystrokes to write. That's also one of the reasons I prefer Python to PHP: `def` is shorter than `function`. There are, of course, far more compelling reasons than that. ;-)

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Totally agree on PEP8 being a guideline. We use flake8 (which combines pyflakes and pep8.py), and I figured that there was *something* that would satisfy the spirit of PEP8 as well as the linters.

Comment: This is wrong (the second line of the assert should only be indented 4 spaces), but it demonstrates how to do it, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

```
ERR_MESSAGE_01 = '''
Some really long error message
'''

assert condition(a,b), ERR_MESSAGE_01
```

Is how I do it ...and I think that complies fine ..

Comment: When the post is talking about PEP-8 compliance, the `CAPS_WITH_UNDERSCORES` names are not helping.

Comment: yeah fair point ... carryover from c #defines and constants. dubious... but im sticking to it .  besides i am thinking of it as a module level constant which pep8 tells us to name as such

Comment: Constants:
Constants are usually defined on a module level and written in all capital letters with underscores separating words. Examples include MAX_OVERFLOW and TOTAL.

Comment: Yes, except in this case, extracting the error message to a module level constant would be awkward (meaning the user would have to jump around to see the value), and `CONDITION()` is a function, not a constant.

Comment: not really I usually create an errors.py module that contains all my error messages as (well named)constants ... obviously not naming them ERR_1 ... also I fixed the function name and the local a,b variable names as you are 100% correct on that front :)  (this also lends itself well to localization)

Answer (score 5):

It's worth noting that it is possible to wrap with parenthesis, just not in the way you are thinking.

```
assert isinstance(some_param_name, 
                  SomeClassName), ('some_param_name must be an instance of '
                                   'SomeClassName, silly goose!')
```

I wouldn't argue it's particularly readable, however. In some cases, it might be the right option.

Answer (score 3):

This is described in pep8 in the end of the [Maximum Line Length](https://pep8.org/#maximum-line-length) section.

> Backslashes may still be appropriate at times. For example, [...] Another such case is with assert statements.

So the pep8 recommendation is to do as mgilsons first example, e.g.:

```py
def afunc(some_param_name):
    assert isinstance(some_param_name, SomeClassName), \ 
           'some_param_name must be an instance of SomeClassName, silly goose!'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def afunc(some_param_name):
    assert (isinstance(some_param_name, SomeClassName)
            ), 'some_param_name must be an instance of SomeClassName, silly goose!'
```

This gives you the implied line continuation from parentheses that is recommended by PEP 8 without breaking the assert behavior.

Alternatively:

```
def afunc(some_param_name):
    assert isinstance(some_param_name, SomeClassName), (
           'some_param_name must be an instance of SomeClassName, silly goose!')
```