# Pretty formatting of long string

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

The string

```
date2check = to_datetime(str(last_tx.year) + \
                        '-' + str(int(last_tx.month)-3) + \
                        '-' + str(last_tx.day) + \
                        ' ' + str(last_tx.hour) + \
                        ':' + str(last_tx.minute) + \
                        ':' + str(last_tx.second))
```

works without problem but I want to know if there is some way to re-write this more appropiately (in a pythonic way). `last_tx` is a datetime object.

Comment: [Here's a similar post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172448/is-it-possible-to-break-a-long-line-to-multiple-lines-in-python#4172465) that should help. Essentially you can escape newlines with a backslash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more pythonic way is to use **[`dateutil.relativedelta`](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html)** (declare 3 months) and **[`datetime.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)** (format datetime). Here is a MWE.

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

three_months = relativedelta(months=3) 
dt = datetime.now() - three_months  # replace `datetime.now()` with `last_tx`

s = dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

print(s)
# Output
2016-02-23 20:37:19
```

---

Previous answer, Use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join),

```
s1 = '-'.join([str(i) for i in [last_tx.year, last_tx.month-3, last_tx.day])
s2 = ':'.join([str(i) for i in [last_tx.hour, last_tx.minute, last_tx.second])

date2check = to_datetime(' ',join([s1, s2]))
```

Comment: I'm getting only two months of difference `2016-05-23 14:27:27 2016-03-23 14:27:27
2016-05-22 21:20:08 2016-03-22 21:20:08
2016-05-23 13:40:20 2016-03-23 13:40:20` ¿Do you know why?

Comment: @JuanDavid, replace the argument `month` (absolute information) with `months` (relative information).

Answer (score 3):

A pythonic way is using `datetime` module in order to get the date of 3 moth ago:

```
datetime.strftime(last_tx-timedelta(90),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Here is an example:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 23, 23, 3, 34, 588744)
>>> datetime.strftime(datetime.now()-timedelta(90),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
'2016-03-24 23:03:38'
```

As @ sparkandshine mentioned in comment, since 90 doesn't always represent 3 month you can use `dateutil.relativedelta` in order to achieve an exact match.

Comment: 90 days (`timedelta(90)`) are not always equivalent to 3 months. Is it better to use `relativedelta(month=3)`?

Comment: Thanks to mention me in your answer. You earned my upvote:-)