# Initialize complex nested lists in Python in many lines?

Tags: python, syntax, indentation

Python requires indenting. So, how to initialize complex nested objects inline?

Should I write them in one long line

```
rewards = [[-0.04, -0.04, -0.04, -0.04], [-0.04, 0, -0.04, -0.04], [-0.04, -0.04, -0.04,-0.04]]
```

Or can I wrap them somehow?

**UPDATE**

My question is not about breaking long lines, which is clearly written in documentation, but about breaking long lines in case of defining complex nested structures, like list of lists of dictionaries of lists. I was unable to beleive we should use line continutaion syntax here.

**UPDATE 1**

No it's not a duplicate.

Comment: inline? you mean in a python interactive shell?

Comment: inside parenthesis, including `[`, `{`, and `(`, you can use any formatting you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to break a long line to multiple lines in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172448/is-it-possible-to-break-a-long-line-to-multiple-lines-in-python)

Comment: @thebjorn this is the answer, please post it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside parenthesis, including `[`, `{`, and `(`, you can use any formatting you want.

Answer (score 9):

One way is to use:

```
rewards = [
    [-0.04, -0.04, -0.04, -0.04],
    [-0.04, 0, -0.04, -0.04],
    [-0.04, -0.04, -0.04,-0.04]
]
```

Note that any whitespace within a list for separating elements is redundant, as the lexer will remove it; so this is simply a matter of readability as per one's taste.

You could write it in one line, however, you will very easily hit the 80 char limit when doing so with long nested lists, and I personally don't find that representation reader friendly.

Comment: Sorry, you are absolutely right, but I am accepting @theborn's answer, because his explanation for me non-pythonian was the what I missed

Comment: @Dims no worries :)

Answer (score 0):

You may wrap any line in Python with a trailing backslash:

```
rewards = [[-0.04, -0.04, -0.04, -0.04], \
[-0.04, 0, -0.04, -0.04], [-0.04, -0.04, -0.04,-0.04]]
```

Still it's not *really* needed here, as it's mentioned in the previous answer

Comment: This is a place where you don't need (and really shouldn't) use a line-continuation character.

Comment: No, it really isn't :-)  You can remove it without effecting the semantics -- and if you want it more readable you should do what @mu did and provide proper semantic formatting ;-)