# Why isn't this ASCII art printing on multiple lines despite being a multiline string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ascii-art

I have created a constant which contains some ASCII art of a triangle, like this:

```
ascii_triangle ='''       /\
     /  \
    /    \
   /      \
  /        \
 /__________\ '''
```

I then use this as the argument for a function, so I can use the picture within a function (along with some other ASCII art and other arguments). The function isn't important, but the problem is that when I try to print it using

```
print(ascii_triangle)
```

within the function, the output looks like this:

```
       /         /          /           /            /             /__________\
```

How can I make it look like a proper triangle?

Comment: Please look at how to provide a [mcve].

Comment: You need to a) use raw strings (`r'''`) or b) escape the \ with another \ -> \\

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ascii-art you posted has a trailing backslash ***just before each newline***. This backslash if not followed by anything besides a newline is treated as the [*line continuation character*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172448/is-it-possible-to-break-a-long-line-to-multiple-lines-in-python).

Observe:

```
In [118]: x = 'foo \
     ...: bar \
     ...: baz'

In [119]: x
Out[119]: 'foo bar baz'
```

In the example above, there is *nothing after the trailing backslash*, so python believes it is a single string without any newlines. The same treatment is given even if you have a multiline quote for a string.

You'll need to *add a space* after the backslash, and make your string a raw literal.

```
In [123]: ascii_triangle =r'''      /\ 
     ...:      /  \ 
     ...:     /    \ 
     ...:    /      \ 
     ...:   /        \ 
     ...:  /__________\ '''

In [124]: print(ascii_triangle)
      /\ 
     /  \ 
    /    \ 
   /      \ 
  /        \ 
 /__________\
```

Try adding a space after the backslash in the first example, and you'd get

```
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Indicating python will require a multiline quote for the string.