# List comprehension Python with multiple control flow

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am trying to convert this function:

```
templist = []
for each in characters:
    if each in vowels:
        templist.append('v')
    elif (each in alphabet) & (each not in vowels):
        templist.append('c')
    else:
        templist.append('?')
characters = templist
print(characters)
```

into list comprehension

```
modified_list = ['v' for each in characters for item in vowels 
                     if item in vowels 
                 else 'c' if (item in alphabet) & (item not in vowels)
                 else '?']`
```

Kinda stuck here! Can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Why are you using `&` instead of `and`?

Comment: Also, why do you want to cram everything into a list comprehension? The original code format is much more readable.

Comment: Yes, and note, if you ever *do* read your elif, the `not in vowels` will *always be `True`, since you already first check `if each in vowels`

Comment: @roganjosh you want to use list comprehensions where you can as list comprehensions gain performance boosts in python. In this case, a list comprehension is the best structure to use to iterate *and* return a list. If they were just iterating a loop and not expecting an array out of it, a normal for loop would be most performant.

Comment: @adambullmer I'm actually not sure that your solution is any faster than the OP's original code (though I'm not saying it's not an elegant approach). You now have a function call overhead for every item in the list (which may or may not balance against `append` cost). You'd have to use `timeit` to see.

Comment: Its class assignment. @roganjosh

Comment: @adambullmer I *highly highly* disagree. You should use a list-comprehension where it is *readable*, doesn't use side-effects, and you want a `list` as an end-result. The performance gains from list-comprehensions are marginal.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it's best to make a function to be called in your list comprehension. Still gives you the speed improvements of a list comprehension while cleaning up the insides a bit.

```
def char_code(character):
  if character in vowels:
    return 'v'
  elif character in alphabet:
    return 'c'
  else:
    return '?'

print([char_code(c) for c in characters])
```

Answer (score 3):

You had several errors in your comprehension syntax.  Most of all, you inserted your `for` clause into the middle of your conditional expression; it has to go at the end of the expression.

```
modified_list = ['v' if each in vowels else
                ('c' if each in alphabet else '?')
                     for each in characters]
```

I also removed the useless `for` clauses, and the redundant test for a consonant: when you're in the `else` clause of your expression, you already know it's not a vowel -- no need to re-test.

**FULL TEST**

vowels = "aeiou"
alphabet = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"
characters = "Now is the time"

```
templist = []
for each in characters:
    if each in vowels:
        templist.append('v')
    elif (each in alphabet) & (each not in vowels):
        templist.append('c')
    else:
        templist.append('?')

print("     original", ''.join(templist))

modified_list = ['v' if each in vowels else \
                ('c' if (each in alphabet) else '?') \
                     for each in characters]

print("comprehension", ''.join(modified_list))
```

Output:

```
     original ?vc?vc?ccv?cvcv
comprehension ?vc?vc?ccv?cvcv
```

Comment: `\\` is not required inside brackets of any kind!

Comment: Right.  Local coding convention, just so we don't have to remember.

Answer (score 1):

just a line breaking style mention: [Is it possible to break a long line to multiple lines in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172448/is-it-possible-to-break-a-long-line-to-multiple-lines-in-python) shows some options

the list comp brackets in this case make `\` unnecessary

sometimes I play with leading space inside the line continuation to indicate logical hiearchy - the leading space is syntactically ignored inside a code line continuation

```
['v' if each in vowels
     else ('c' if each in alphabet
               else '?')
 for each in characters]
```