# How to split a long python one-liner?

Tags: python

I have a long line that `pylint` is complaining is breaking `pep8 E501`

```
count_approvers = self.leave_not_required_user.company.leave_approvers.count()
```

How can I split this over 2 lines?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172448/is-it-possible-to-break-a-long-line-to-multiple-lines-in-python

Comment: I mean, you can just break the line with `\\`... it's a trivial question ;)

Comment: I don't think this is a particularly long one-liner, although it might be longer with indentation.

Comment: Aha, thank you. I didn't know you could do this. If you look at the "duplicate" question there are no examples with a pure code line. They all have strings.

Comment: Also, instead of splitting the one-liner over multiple lines, IMHO making it less readable, consider making it _not_ a one-liner, e.g. defining  `comp = self.leave_not_required_user.company` first.

Comment: read this Python pep8 coding guidelines.  https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a temporary alias, if you may:

```
company = self.leave_not_required_user.company 
count_approvers = company.leave_approvers.count()
```

Answer (score 3):

Configure your pylint for length of line. Or you can use '\' after '='

```
count_approvers = \
        self.leave_not_required_user.company.leave_approvers.count()
```