# What is the \ in python do?

Tags: python-3.x

I created a small program using the ASCII table. I am encrypting the string the user inputs. What I'm confused about is the "\" is its division? Or what is it separating?

```
plainText = input("Enter a one-word, lowercase message: ")
distance = int(input("Enter the distance value: "))
code = ""
for ch in plainText:
    ordValue = ord(ch)
    print(1, ordValue)
    print(2, ch)
    cipherValue = ordValue + distance
    print(3, cipherValue)
    if cipherValue > ord('z'):
#                                    what does "\" stand for 
        cipherValue = ord('a') + distance - \
                      (ord('z') - ordValue + 1)
        print(4, cipherValue)
    code += chr(cipherValue)
    print(5, code)
```

Comment: I believe it escapes the newline character that immediately follows it, so that it doesn't cause issues with parsing.

Comment: it's just a line continuation so you can break the code across multiple lines. does not have any impact on the program.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172448/is-it-possible-to-break-a-long-line-to-multiple-lines-in-python/4172465 for reference

Comment: It's a line continuation character, that allows one long line of code to be broken into multiple lines.

Comment: interesting that makes sense I got help from someone else but never it made it clear. thank you @RickTeachey

Comment: thank you for the link @StardustGogeta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\` escapes the newline. That means that if the line is an expression, it tells the parser to use the next line as part of the same line.

So

```py
x + 2 + \
  3
```

is the same as `x + 2 + 3`.

This is especially helpful with a bunch of repeated method calls, like:

```py
my_object \
  .method_a() \
  .method_b(c) \
  .method_d(e=f) \
  .method_g()
```

which can sometimes be more readable than `my_object.method_a().method_b(c).method_d(e=f).method_g()`

More about this behavior can be found in [the Python language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#explicit-line-joining).

Comment: Can you include references?

Comment: @Jab I included a link to the Python language reference's documentation on `\` in the syntax/grammar of Python

Answer (score 0):

Forward slash is division [ / ]. You're using backslash [ \ ] which is the [escape character](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html) for python. If you use it alone at the end of the line, it merges the line the slash is on and the next line into one statement. [Like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53162/how-can-i-do-a-line-break-line-continuation-in-python)