# Python: Combining Lists into 1 but splitting the Code to do on on Multiple Lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this:

```
new_list = list_a + list_b + list_c
```

I want to format it so it looks like this:

```
new_list =
     list_a +
     list_b +
     list_c
```

for readability and QA purposes, how can I do this? When I try to do this, I get an `Invalid Format` error.

**Edit:**
This does not answer my question: [How can I do a line break (line continuation) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53162/how-can-i-do-a-line-break-line-continuation-in-python)

When I try to do the following:

```
new_list = (
     a,
     b,
     c
)
```

I get this:

```
new_list

[[values_from_list_a],[values_from_list_b],[values_from_list_c]]
```

I want this:

```
['values_from_list_a','values_from_list_b','values_from_list_c']
```

Comment: How does that other question not answer yours?

Comment: I want to combine multiple lists into 1. What the other post did was have a list made up of separate lists (see the brackets inside the brackets).

Comment: Perhaps this is more helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172448/is-it-possible-to-break-a-long-line-to-multiple-lines-in-python

Comment: Ah, that's what I was doing wrong. Got it.

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parentheses

```
new_list = (
  list_a + 
  list_b + 
  list_c
)
```

Comment: Ah, that's what I was doing wrong, I was using commas instead of + signs.