# Binarization in Spyder(Python 3.9) code using sk-learn(preprocessing) and NumPy

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn, spyder, np

[I attach a screenshot of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYuYL.png)
I am new to Python and am currently studying artificial intelligence, working in Spyder(python 3.9)

After executing the code, I expected this output

```
Binarized data:
    [[1.о.1.]
    [о.1.о.]
    [1.о.о.]
    [1.о.о.]]
```

Comment: Remove the space after = or put \ after =

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python it is important to write **one** command in **one** line:

```
data_binarized = preprocessing.Binarizer(your_code)
```

If you want to write it in two lines, you can use implicit line continuation (Possible **only** inside parentheses, brackets and braces):

```
data_binarized = preprocessing.Binarizer(
                 your_code)
```

As an second possible option you can use the backslash (explicit line continuation):

```
data_binarized =\
preprocessing.Binarizer(your_code)
```

For more information about this look at this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4172465/21187993