# What does the .\ operator mean in Python?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am studying TensorFlow through this github repository

https://github.com/deeplearningzerotoall/TensorFlow/blob/master/tf_2.x/lab-10-1-1-mnist_nn_softmax.ipynb

and I don't understand what `.\` means here:

```
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_x, train_y)).\
    shuffle(buffer_size=100000).\
    prefetch(buffer_size=batch_size).\
    batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=True)
```

Comment: \ is a python's line break.

Comment: .\ isn't an operator; as others have explained, \ is used to *continue* to the next line.  In this example, it just happens that each line to be continued ended with a `.`.

Comment: Please see also how a code like this should have been formatted: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8683240/5378816

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backslash is used to escape the next character, which is a newline in this case. This allows to split the long call chain to multiple lines.

Comment: How come, if it works even when you add a space after the backslash?

Comment: thanks! but it isn't work when add a space it just works next character is newline