# Newline issue with fluent interface (method chaining)

Tags: python

I am trying to write a Python class that will allow me to use it in code like this:

```
mc = MyClass()
mc.foo()
  .bar()
```

I have written the class like this:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def foo(self):
        print "foo called"
        return self
    def bar(self):
        print "bar called"
        return self
```

However, the only way I can get close to the "beautiful" style I want, is to introduce backslashes like so (run in both IPython and IDLE):

```
>>> mc = MyClass()
>>> mc.foo()\
       .bar()
```

Is there any way I can do without the backslashes?

Comment: Never thought about it by to my understanding this is not possible. Each tab and new line is a new execution in Python. Unless backslashes are used. So my answer would be, no.

Comment: You can put the whole thing in parentheses, but that probably doesn't make it any prettier.

Comment: No, you can't do that. Why would you want to? *Explicit is better than implicit* (`import this`).

Comment: I just tested this in spider, and I agree, since `mc.foo().bar()` is the command and `.bar()` is not an entire command on its own

Comment: @jonrsharpe This is not about implicit vs. explicit. If `mc.foo().bar()` is okay, then a couple of newline characters shouldn't suddenly mean we are violating pythonic guidelines. See http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html for more on why this approach can be nice in certain situations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to break a line of chained methods in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768941/how-to-break-a-line-of-chained-methods-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

No. Python is layout-dependent, and newlines (unless enclosed in brackets or escaped using a backslash) terminate a statement. As far as I'm aware, there is no way to bend it to accept this syntax.

What makes you want to do that? Personally, I would argue against it based on readability. Both the alternatives below seem clearer to me, and I'd prefer the latter (when method names are sufficiently short and simple).

```
mc = MyClass()
x = mc.foo()
x.bar()

mc = MyClass()
mc.foo().bar()
```

As, in this case, you know the result of `foo()` is of type `MyClass`, you might even just call it as follows. When possible, this is definitely the preferable method (and you can omit the return statements altogether).

```
mc = MyClass()
mc.foo()
mc.bar()
```

Comment: Or even just `mc.foo(); mc.bar()`; there's no need for the methods to `return self`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe note that while that would work for this example, as `self` is returned, it is not a general translation from `mc.foo().bar()`. Good call though, I added an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can enclose your command in parenthesis. Python, does not "finishes" a command while there is a open parenthesis. It is not perfect, but useful if you chain a lot of commands:

```
mc = MyClass()
(mc.foo()
   .bar())
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently invoked a fluent interface, like this:

```py
mc = MyClass()
mc.foo(
 ).bar(
 )
```

Assuming foo and bar have parameters, which they did in my case, you can dedicate a line (or more) to the parameters of each function:

```py
mc = MyClass()
mc.foo(foo_par1, foo_par2, foo_par3
 ).bar(bar_par1, bar_par2
 )
```