# Python PIL save file with datetime as name

Tags: python, datetime, python-imaging-library, video-capture

I'm relatively new to python and know very little syntax, but I'm willing to learn as much as possible. Simply put I want to use the save feature in PIL to save a .png with the file's name being the current date and time. This may be complicated by the fact that I'm not using PIL directly, but through the Videocapture module, but i doubt it. this is my code that works

```
from VideoCapture import Device
cam = Device()
cam.saveSnapshot('C:\Users\Myname\Dropbox\Foldes\image.png', timestamp=3, boldfont=1, textpos='bc')
```

Its short, but it does what I need it to.
I realize Datetime will need to be imported, But I can't get the data as the name without errors. yes i have tried the str() command. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
'C:\Users\Myname\Dropbox\Foldes\image.png'
```

In strings in Python, backslashes have special meaning so you need to treat them differently. You can either use two of them instead of one...

```
'C:\\Users\\Myname\\Dropbox\\Foldes\\image.png'
```

...or you can put an `r` before the string (as long as it doesn't end with a backslash)

```
r'C:\Users\Myname\Dropbox\Foldes\image.png'
```

---

To generate a string containing the current day in `YYYY-MM-DD-HH:MM` format, we can use the datetime module like this. To format the timestamp differently, consult [the documentation here](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

```
import datetime
date_string = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M")
```

As a shorter alternative, you could use the similar `time` module instead:

```
import time
date_string = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M")
```

After this, you should just be able to do

```
cam.saveSnapshot(r'C:\Users\Myname\Dropbox\Foldes\image-' + date_string + '.png',
                 timestamp=3, boldfont=1, textpos='bc')
```

to save the image with the datetime in the filename. (I have split the function call over two lines for readability, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53162/how-can-i-do-a-line-break-line-continuation-in-python) for some explanation of how this works.)

Comment: **from time import strftime** will be simpler

Comment: @eyquem Thanks for the suggestion, I have added it to the answer.

Comment: **from time import strftime** avoids to import all the content of the module **time**

Comment: @eyquem I think that's incorrect; Python loads modules all-at-once, the import options only control which names are added to the current namespace (in this case, `time` vs `strftime`).

Comment: @Jeremy Banks I didn't know. That solves an interrogation I had: how does it work when an imported function of a module needs other functions of the module that are not specifically imported by another **from module import ...** But I would like to have official reference on this point.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but for future record. the 'C:\Users\Myname\Dropbox\Foldes\image.png' worked just fine

Comment: @robocop That's interesting. Looking into it, it apparently works fine in most cases (`"C:\Users"`), but fails for things like `"C:\Users\nblah"` because `\n` represents a newline.

Comment: For anyone trying to use this script, the colon in the datetime string was causing an error. I replaced it with a space, and even though it looks funny, the script runs without error.

Comment: note that `:` is not a valid filename character in Windows, but is valid in Linux.