# What does a semicolon do?

Tags: python, function, if-statement, syntax, break

I got a function online to help me with my current project and it had semicolons on some of the lines. I was wondering why? Is it to break the function?

```
def containsAny(self, strings=[]):
    alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'
    for string in strings:
        for char in string:
            if char in alphabet: return 1;
    return 0;
```

The function I got online with little modification:

```
for string in strings:
    for char in string:
        if char in alphabet: return 1;
```

Is the above saying the following?

```
if char in alphabet:
    return 1
    break
```

Comment: Related post - [Why is semicolon allowed in this python snippet?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8236380/465053)

Comment: Related: *[When is semicolon use in Python considered "good" or "acceptable"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19365508/)*

Answer (score 106, accepted):

The semicolon does nothing in the code you show.

I suspect this is someone who programs in another language (C, Java, ...) that requires semicolons at the end of statements and it's just a habit (happens to me sometimes too).

If you want to put several Python statements on the same line, you can use a semi-colon to separate them, see this [Python Doc](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html):

> A suite is a group of statements controlled by a clause. A suite can
>   be one or more semicolon-separated simple statements on the same line
>   as the header, following the header’s colon, or it can be one or more
>   indented statements on subsequent lines

Comment: Semicolons can [suppress output in IPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56572156/does-a-semicolon-at-the-end-of-a-python-statement-suppress-output#comment99722886_56572156).

Answer (score 19):

The semicolon here does not do anything. People who come from C/C++/Java/(many other language) backgrounds tend to use the semicolon out of habit.

Answer (score 2):

In general the semicolon does nothing. But if you are using the [Jupyter Notebook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython#Project_Jupyter) (depending on your version), you might get a figure plotted twice. The semicolon at the end of your plot command prevents this:

```
df.plot();
```

Comment: Yes, this is much better than the speculation about motives...

Answer (score 1):

Programmers of C, C++, and Java are habituated of using a semicolon to tell the compiler that this is the end of a statement, but for Python this is not the case.

The reason is that in Python, newlines are an unambiguous way of separating code lines; this is by design, and the way this works has been thoroughly thought through. As a result, Python code is perfectly readable and unambiguous without any special end-of-statement markers (apart from the newline).

Comment: "has been thoroughly thought through" -- It's not everyday that you can see those 3 words back to back in a normal conversation

Answer (score 0):

As other answers point out, the semicolon does nothing there. It's a separator (e.g. `print 1;print 2`). But it does not work like this: `def func():print 1;print 2;;print'Defined!'` (`;;` is a syntax error). Out of habit, people tend to use it (as it is required in languages such as C/Java...).