# Why is a semicolon working in Python and does not result in an error?

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error

I am using Python 2.7.

I have been experimenting with the interpreter and found out the following unusual thing. I wrote the following code and it's working:

```
    def func():
        a = 5 ;
        print a
```

When I call this function, it gives the required output in the interpreter, not giving any syntax error, despite using the semicolon. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Why is it not giving a *syntax error*?

Comment: Who said that they don't work?

Comment: you can use it to use multiple statements in single line

Comment: semicolons are optional in python, however if there are two statements in a single line, semicolon is mandatory to separate.

Comment: found them useful in `python -c "..."` commands

Comment: if you check the grammar file of python, you will find this statement, `simple_stmt: small_stmt (';' small_stmt)* [';'] NEWLINE` , semicolon is optional from that grammar .http://docs.python.org/2/reference/grammar.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don’t use semicolons to end a statement in Python!

But look here to see why it’s allowed: *[Why is semicolon allowed in this Python snippet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236380/why-is-semicolon-allowed-in-this-python-snippet)*

Or here: *[What does a semicolon do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335358/python-what-does-a-semi-colon-do)*

They are used to put multiple statements on a single line, so the interpreter is just ignoring it since there is not a second statement.

Comment: Re *"don’t use semicolons to end a statement in Python"*: Semicolons are used for [suppressing output in IPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56572156/semicolon-at-end-of-python-statement-suppresses-output#comment99722886_56572156).

Answer (score 1):

Using semicolon is the way to write several statement in one line. Second is empty in your code.