# Does a semicolon at the end of a Python statement suppress output?

Tags: python, syntax, ipython

[According to Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335358/what-does-a-semicolon-do/12335362#12335362) [and Quora](http://www.quora.com/What-happens-if-the-semicolon-is-placed-at-the-end-of-the-statement-in-Python), a semicolon at the end of a Python statement does nothing.  When I type `dir()` at the IPython prompt, I see a list of variables in my namespace.  If I type `dir();`, however, I see nothing.  What could explain this?

I am getting to know Python 3.7 using [Spyder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spyder_%28software%29), installed using [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)).

Comment: It’s an [IPython-specific feature](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/tips.html#suppress-output). You won’t see the same behaviour in the normal Python REPL, for example.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: Just weighing whether where I got it from is a good duplicate :)

Comment: What is the canonical question? The two existing duplicates are too specific (two specific problems, not about the general-used feature of using semicolon to suppress output).