# Separating commands with semicolons in Python

Tags: python, syntax

Why are semicolon separated statements only partly valid?

**Valid:**

```
import sys;print "x";print "test"
```

**Valid:**

```
for x in [1,2,3]:print x
```

**Error:**

```
import sys;for x in [1,2,3]:print x
```

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335358/python-what-does-a-semi-colon-do