# SyntaxError when assigning to global var

Tags: python

I am trying out Python for a new project, and in that state, need some global variable. To test without changing the hardcoded value, I've tried to make a function that reassign thoses variables:

```
foo = None;

def setFoo(bar):
    global foo = bar;

setFoo(1);
```

However, this get:

```
  File ".\test.py", line 4
    global foo = bar;
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've already read [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588317/python-function-global-variables) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them) higly related to my problem, but obviously missed some gotcha of Python.

Could anyone enlighten me?

Comment: `global foo` and `foo = bar` on separate lines.

Comment: As a side note, you do not need to use ';' to end the line. Python does not need them.

Comment: Well, that was a simple gotcha.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python function global variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588317/python-function-global-variables)

Comment: @TeemuRisikko: I know, but coming from C, I use them whenever I can, even in JS. It's sort of a reflex, and don't hurt the code.

Comment: Everything has been said, except maybe that global variable are a bad practice in general. If you have a bunch of methods and want to share variables globally, why not. But I would structure the code with classes and avoid using globvars ;)

Comment: @khelwood: Could be, what I was missing was that `global` was a statement on its own.

Comment: @DrakaSAN Yep, but there are answers in those questions that clearly state the correct syntax.

Comment: You should write Python as Python, not as C. Semicolons *are* required in JS, it is just that they are inferred where not present. That is not true of Python; you should not use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`global` and assignment are both statements. You can't mix them on the same line.

Answer (score 2):

```
foo = None;

def setFoo(bar):
    global foo 
    foo = bar

setFoo(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

As saurabh baid pointed out, the correct syntax is

```
foo = None

def set_foo(bar):
    global foo 
    foo = bar

set_foo(1)
```

Using the `global` keyword allows the function to access the global scope (i.e. the scope of the module)

Also notice how I renamed the variables to be `snake_case` and removed the semi-colons. semi-colons are unnecessary in Python, and functions are typically `snake_case` :)

Comment: "shouldn't be used" Why? From what I read, they are unneccessary, but don't hurt readability nor code quality.

Comment: @DrakaSAN, it's generally seen as unPythonic, though I suppose there are reasons to use them in rare cases like multiple statements on one line, but personally I can't see why you'd add more noise to a program

Comment: @DrakaSAN They certainly do hurt the readability, by introducing redundant punctuation in a way not consistent with the expected use of the language. Don't try and write Python like it's C.

Answer (score 0):

`global` and `foo = bar` on separate lines

```
foo = None

def setFoo(bar):
    global foo
    foo = bar

setFoo(1)
```

don't use semicolon:
[Python: What Does a Semi Colon Do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335358/python-what-does-a-semi-colon-do)

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't require you to explicitly declare variables and automatically assumes that a variable that you assign has function scope unless you tell it otherwise. The `global` keyword is the means that is provided to tell it otherwise. And you can't assign value when you declare it as global. Correct way will be

```
foo = None

def setFoo(bar):
    global foo 
    foo = bar

setFoo(1)
```