# Is Using Semi-Colons in python looked down upon?

Tags: python

I am fairly good at python but I am wondering if using semi colons is looked down upon in any way. When I see code snippets online or I look at friends code etc I don't see them. If they **are** looked down upon, why? I don't see a problem with them. I would use them like this for example:

```
print("What you do want {}?".format(name));choice = input(">> ")
```

Comment: Why does it need to be on one line would be my question

Comment: They add nothing. Why use them? Use `choice = input("What you do want {}?".format(name)\n>> ")` instead. *>looking down on them<*  See [python-what-does-a-semicolon-do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335358/python-what-does-a-semicolon-do)

Comment: Python has established coding style guidelines   https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236380/why-is-semicolon-allowed-in-this-python-snippet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's normally discouraged as it detracts from readability, from [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> Compound statements (multiple statements on the same line) are
>   generally discouraged.
>
> Yes:
>
> ```
> if foo == 'blah':
>     do_blah_thing()
> do_one()
> do_two()
> do_three()
> ```
>
> Rather not:
>
> ```
> if foo == 'blah': do_blah_thing()
> do_one(); do_two(); do_three()
> ```
>
> While sometimes it's okay to put an if/for/while with a small body on
>   the same line, never do this for multi-clause statements. Also avoid
>   folding such long lines!
>
> Rather not:
>
> ```
> if foo == 'blah': do_blah_thing()
> for x in lst: total += x
> while t < 10: t = delay()
> ```
>
> Definitely not:
>
> ```
> if foo == 'blah': do_blah_thing()
> else: do_non_blah_thing()
>
> try: something()
> finally: cleanup()
>
> do_one(); do_two(); do_three(long, argument,
>                              list, like, this)
>
> if foo == 'blah': one(); two(); three()
> ```