# what is the use of ';' in python. I don't see a document that explains this

Tags: python, expression

I have no idea what `;` is in python. 
I saw people using

```
print(x) ; print(y)
```

But I don't see a document that explains this. 
I want a document that explains this.

Comment: In python, the semicolon (;) signifies an end of a line of code. So if you want to put multiple lines of code on the same line, you separate them with a semicolon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is semicolon allowed in this python snippet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236380/why-is-semicolon-allowed-in-this-python-snippet)

Comment: You also find informations about the semicolon here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335358/python-what-does-a-semicolon-do

Comment: Seeing as you want a document, here is a link to the official docs - [Compound statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html): `A suite can be one or more semicolon-separated simple statements on the same line as the header, following the header’s colon, or it can be one or more indented statements on subsequent lines.`

Comment: @BoobyTrap i haven't seen your comment before posting an answer, if you wish i can delete it in favor of your comment.:)

Comment: @vishes_shell No worries, keep it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your question states as, you want a document:

Here is [Compound statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#compound-statements):

> A suite can be one or more semicolon-separated simple statements on the same line as the header, following the header’s colon, or it can be one or more indented statements on subsequent lines.