# Overriding functions, see that there is a bool defined in class

Tags: python, html-parsing, global

I am trying to parse some html page in python. When i reach a certain tag, i would like to start printing all the data. So far i came up with this:

```
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    start = False;
    counter = 0;
    def handle_starttag(self,tag,attrs):
        if(tag == 'TBODY'):
            start = True;
            counter +=1
            #if counter == 1
    def handle_data(self,data):
        if (start == True): # this is the error line
            print data
```

The problem is that there is an error saying that it doesn't know what start is. I know i could use the global, but that wouldn't force me to define the variable outside the whole class?

EDIT:
Changing start to self.start solves the problem, but is there a way to define it inside **init** without messing up the HTMLParser init?

Comment: use the `self` keyword (I'd suggest you pass a Python tutorial first)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    start = False;
    counter = 0;
    ...
```

This does not do what you think it does!

In Java, C#, or similar languages, what the analogous code does is declare that the class of objects known as `MyHTMLParser` all have an attribute `start` with the initial value of `False`, and `counter` with the initial value of `0`.

In Python **classes are objects too**. They have their own attributes, just like every other object. So what the above does in Python is create a class object named `MyHTMLParser`, with an attribute `start` set to `False` and an attribute `counter` set to `0`.<sup>1</sup>

Another thing to keep in mind is that there is **no way whatsoever** to make an assignment to a bare name like `start = True` set an attribute on an object. It always sets a variable named `start`.<sup>2</sup>

So your class contains no code that ever sets any attributes on any of your `MyHTMLParser` instances; the code in the class body is setting attributes on the class object itself, and the code in `handle_starttag` is setting local variables which are then discarded when they fall out of scope.

Your code in `handle_data` is reading from a local variable named `start` (which you never set), for similar reasons. In Python there is no way to read an attribute without specifying in which object to look for it. A bare `start` is always referring to variable, either in the local function scope or some outer scope. You need `self.start` to read the `start` attribute of the `self` object.

Remember, the `def` block defining a method is nothing special, it's a function like any other. It's only later, when that function happens to be stored in an attribute of a class object, that the function can be classified as a method. So the `self` parameter behaves the same as any other parameter, and indeed any other name. It doesn't have to be named `self` (though that's a wise convention to follow), and it has no special privileges making reads and writes of bare names look for attributes of `self`.

So:

1. Don't define your attributes with their initial values in the class block; that's for values which are shared by all instances of the class, not attributes of each instance. Instance attributes can only be initialised once you have a reference to the particular instance; most commonly this is done in the `__init__` method, which is called as soon as the object exists.
2. You *must* specify in which object you want to read or write attributes. This applies *always*, in *every* context. In particular, you will usually refer to attributes inside methods as `self.attribute`.

Applying that (and eliminating the semicolons, which you don't need in Python):

```
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        start = False
        counter = 0

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if(tag == 'TBODY'):
            self.start = True
            self.counter += 1

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if (self.start == True):
            print data
```

---

<sup>1</sup> The methods `handle_starttag` and `handle_data` are also nothing more than functions which happen to be attributes of an object that is used as a class.

<sup>2</sup> Usually a local variable; if you've declared `start` to be `global` or `nonlocal` then it might be an outer variable. But it's *definitely* not an attribute on some object you happen to have nearby, even if that other object is bound to the name `self`.

Comment: i normally use __init__ to declare the variables, but i cannot override the HTMLParser's init, since it does some of its own initialization.

Comment: Well in that case the proper initialization of your objects is to initialize the attributes you want them to have *plus* do the initialization `HTMLParser` requires. You will need to write an `__init__` method that does this. It is very common to do this when subclassing. You can call `HTMLParser.__init__(self, ...)` from your `__init__` so you don't have to reimplement it (or use `super`, but I don't really recommend that until you've got a good grasp of the basics of Python).

Answer (score 1):

Use the self keyword

```
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        self.start = False;
        self.counter = 0;
    def handle_starttag(self,tag,attrs):
        if(tag == 'TBODY'):
            self.start = True;
            self.counter +=1
            #if counter == 1
    def handle_data(self,data):
        if (self.start == True): # this is the error line
            print data
```

Comment: i cannot override the __init__ function

Comment: In that case use `super().__init__()` which will let you extend the HTMLParser code in your function without overriding it (assuming start and counter aren't in HTMLParser).

Answer (score 0):

As a note, you don't need to put a semicolon `;` at the end of each line. You can use it as a separator to put multiple statements on the same line if necessary. See [Why is semicolon allowed in this python snippet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236380/why-is-semicolon-allowed-in-this-python-snippet)