# How simplify list processing in Python?

Tags: python, list

Here's my first Python program, a little utility that converts from a Unix octal code for file permissions to the symbolic form:

```
s=raw_input("Octal?  ");
digits=[int(s[0]),int(s[1]),int(s[2])];
lookup=['','x','w','wx','r','rx','rw','rwx'];
uout='u='+lookup[digits[0]];
gout='g='+lookup[digits[1]];
oout='o='+lookup[digits[2]];
print(uout+','+gout+','+oout);
```

Are there ways to shorten this code that take advantage of some kind of "list processing"? For example, to apply the `int` function all at once to all three characters of `s` without having to do explicit indexing. And to index into `lookup` using the whole list `digits` at once?

Comment: Are you purposely wanting to use `;` at the end of every line in this script?  This is *Python*, [after all](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8236402/1167750)... :)

Comment: Entirely for fun (don't use this), here is a one-liner: `print(','.join(c+'='+''.join('xw r'[i-1:i&b] for i in (4,2,1)) for c,b in zip('ugo',map(int,raw_input("Octal? ")))))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a slightly optimized version of your code:

```
s = raw_input("Octal?  ")
digits = map(int, s)
lookup = ['','x','w','wx','r','rx','rw','rwx']
perms = [lookup[d] for d in digits]
rights = ['{}={}'.format(*x) for x in zip('ugo', perms)]
print ','.join(rights)
```

Comment: That just taught me more about Python than a whole lot of searching around through docs. (And of course I'm impatient enough not wanting to go through the typical tedious introductory tutorials I've seen.)

Comment: Oops: I'm not seeing the "u=", etc., parts when I run that code interactively using Python 2.7. And the same thing if I execute it as a script under Python 3.3, replacing the `raw_input` line with `import sys` and then `s=sys.argv[1]`, and the last line with `print(','.join(perms))`.

Answer (score 11):

```
digits=[int(s[0]),int(s[1]),int(s[2])];
```

can be written as:

```
digits = map(int,s)
```

or:

```
digits = [ int(x) for x in s ]  #list comprehension
```

As it looks like you might be using python3.x (or planning on using it in the future based on your function-like print usage), you may want to opt for the list-comprehension unless you want to dig in further and use `zip` as demonstrated by one of the later answers.

Comment: +1 for using both [map](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: OP's using `raw_input`, so it's 2.X

Comment: @Blender -- Good point.  I hadn't noticed that (I just saw the function-like print statement).

Comment: Aha! `map` was precisely the sort of function I was looking for, something I'm used to using in *Mathematica* and *J*.

Comment: @Blender: I'm still stumbling around a bit here, and the explicit reading of input was while testing my program interactively (in Spyder). What I'll do is make this an executable script, and for that I'll use `sys.argv[1]` to obtain the input directly from the command line, instead of prompting for and reading input.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do it with bitmasks:

```
masks = {
    0b100: 'r',  # 4
    0b010: 'x',  # 2
    0b001: 'w'   # 1
}

octal = raw_input('Octal? ')
result = '-'

for digit in octal[1:]:
    for mask, letter in sorted(masks.items(), reverse=True):
        if int(digit, 8) & mask:
            result += letter
        else:
            result += '-'

print result
```

Comment: Um, you're relying on the order of `masks.items()`, which is undefined. Don't you mean `sorted(masks.items(), reversed=True)`?

Comment: @LauritzV.Thaulow: Yes, thank you. It's somewhat predictable in CPython.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my version, inspired by Blender's solution:

```
bits = zip([4, 2, 1], "rwx")
groups = "ugo"

s = raw_input("Octal?  ");
digits = map(int, s)

parts = []
for group, digit in zip(groups, digits):
    letters = [letter for bit, letter in bits if digit & bit]
    parts.append("{0}={1}".format(group, "".join(letters)))

print ",".join(parts)
```

I think it's better not to have to explicitly enter the `lookup` list.

Comment: "Six of one, half dozen of the other"?? Terser code if one forms the `lookup` list vs. longer code but longer clode while closer to the spirit of how permissions are calculated with the `bits` manipulation. I like little problems that are so rich in possible solutions. Thanks to all contributors here.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my crack at it (including '-' for missing permissions):

```
lookup = {
    0b000 : '---',
    0b001 : '--x',
    0b010 : '-w-',
    0b011 : '-wx',
    0b100 : 'r--',
    0b101 : 'r-x',
    0b110 : 'rw-',
    0b111 : 'rwx'
}

s = raw_input('octal?: ')
print(','.join( # using ',' as the delimiter
               r + '=' + lookup[int(n, 8)] # the letter followed by the permissions
               for n, r  in zip(tuple(s), 'ugo'))) # for each number/ letter pair
```