# OpenGL 4.2+ and shader_image_load_store for 3D textures not working?

Tags: python, opengl, glsl, gpu, opengl-4

I am trying to figure out why I'm not able to write into 3D textures using the (now built-in) shader_image_load_store extension.

I created two simple examples (in python to make it easier): one to write into a 2D texture, that works, and one to write into a 3D texture that does not work

the (working) 2D version is as following:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt4.QtOpenGL import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
import sys

iTexSize = 256


_vsClearSource =  """
    #version 440 compatibility
    void main() {
        gl_Position = ftransform();
        gl_FrontColor = gl_Color;
    }
    """     

_fsClearSource =   """
#version 440 compatibility
uniform int         iPrimitiveCount;
uniform int         iSliceIndex;

layout(size4x32, binding=0) coherent uniform   image2D volColorVolume;
const int iMaxTexSize = 255;  

void main() {
    ivec2 ivecVolumeCoordinate = ivec2(gl_FragCoord.x, gl_FragCoord.y ); //, iSliceIndex);

    vec4 vecVolumeValue =  vec4(0,1,0,1); // vec4(         float(iSlabIndex)/float(iPrimitiveCount)); //,0.0,0.0,0.0);

   imageStore(volColorVolume, ivecVolumeCoordinate, vecVolumeValue);                  
   gl_FragData[0] = vec4(1,0,1,1);
}    
    """    

_fsFillSource =   """
#version 440 compatibility
uniform int         iPrimitiveCount;
uniform int         iSliceIndex;

layout(size4x32, binding=0) coherent uniform   image2D volColorVolume;
const int iMaxTexSize = 255;  

void main() {
    ivec2 ivecVolumeCoordinate = ivec2(gl_FragCoord.x, gl_FragCoord.y );

    vec4 vecVolumeValue =  vec4( float(gl_FragCoord.x)  / float(iMaxTexSize)  , float(gl_FragCoord.y)  / float(iMaxTexSize)  , 0 ,  1  );

   imageStore(volColorVolume, ivecVolumeCoordinate, vecVolumeValue);                  
   gl_FragData[0] = vec4(1,0,1,1);
}    
"""       



class Viewer3DWidget(QGLWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        QGLWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.uWidth = 0
        self.uHeight = 0

        self.texColorTexture = None
        self.fboRendering    = None
        self.texColorVolume = None

        self.vecBackgroundColor = (1.,1.,1.)

        self.vecDrawBuffers = [ GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 , GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1 , GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT3, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT4, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT5 ]


        self.fSurfacesSpacing = 1.0
        self.fSurfacesTransparency = 1.0






    def initializeGL(self):
        self.shaShaderFill = QGLShaderProgram(self.context())
        self.shaShaderFill.addShaderFromSourceCode(QGLShader.Vertex, _vsClearSource)
        self.shaShaderFill.addShaderFromSourceCode(QGLShader.Fragment, _fsFillSource)   
        self.shaShaderFill.link()      

        self.shaShaderClear = QGLShaderProgram(self.context())
        self.shaShaderClear.addShaderFromSourceCode(QGLShader.Vertex, _vsClearSource)
        self.shaShaderClear.addShaderFromSourceCode(QGLShader.Fragment, _fsClearSource)   
        self.shaShaderClear.link()       



        glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
        glClearDepth(1.0)


    def initRenderTargets(self):
        global iTexSize
        if (self.texColorTexture is None):
            self.texColorTexture = glGenTextures( 1 )
        if (self.fboRendering is  None):
            self.fboRendering = glGenFramebuffers(1)               

        glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, self.texColorTexture )
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP)
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP)
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, 0, GL_RGBA32F, iTexSize, iTexSize, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, None)


        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, 0);

        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, self.fboRendering)
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE,  self.texColorTexture, 0)
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0)    


    def deleteRenderTargets(self):
        if (self.fboAccumulation is  not  None):
            glDeleteFramebuffers(1,self.fboRendering)          
            self.fboAccumulation = None
        if (self.texColorTexture is not None):
            glDeleteTextures( self.texColorTexture )
            self.texColorTexture = None


    def initColorVolume(self):
        if (self.texColorVolume is None):
            self.texColorVolume = glGenTextures( 1 )


        glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.texColorVolume )
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP)
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP)
        #glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP)
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, iTexSize, iTexSize, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, None);


        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);    



    def fillVolume(self, bClear):
        global iTexSize

        shaShader = self.shaShaderClear
        if(not bClear):
            shaShader = self.shaShaderFill

        if (not self.fboRendering):
            self.initRenderTargets() 

        if (not self.texColorVolume):
            self.initColorVolume()

        glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION )
        glLoadIdentity()

        glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
        glLoadIdentity();            



        glBindImageTexture(0,self.texColorVolume,0,GL_FALSE,0,GL_READ_WRITE,GL_RGBA32F);

        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, self.fboRendering);
        glDrawBuffers(1, self.vecDrawBuffers);

        glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);            

        shaShader.bind()

        shaShader.setUniformValue("iPrimitiveCount", iTexSize)  
        shaShader.setUniformValue("volColorVolume", 0) 

        for i in range(iTexSize):


            shaShader.setUniformValue("iSliceIndex", i) 




            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glVertex2f(-1.0, -1.0); 
            glVertex2f(1.0, -1.0);
            glVertex2f(1.0, 1.0);
            glVertex2f(-1.0, 1.0);
            glEnd();


            #sync
            glMemoryBarrier(GL_ALL_BARRIER_BITS);


        glBindImageTexture(0,0,0,GL_FALSE,0,GL_READ_WRITE,GL_RGBA32F);
        shaShader.release()

        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);


    def paintGL(self):
        if  (self.uWidth is 0):
            return           
        if (not self.fboRendering):
            self.initRenderTargets() 
            self.initColorVolume()

        glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION )
        glLoadIdentity()

        glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
        glLoadIdentity();

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)


        self.fillVolume(True)
        #draw into the volume
        self.fillVolume(False)

        #slice the volume
        self.displayTexture()



        glFlush()




    def displayTexture(self):   #essentially not useable here
        glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION )
        glLoadIdentity()
        glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
        glLoadIdentity();
        glDisable(GL_BLEND)
        glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);  
        glDisable(GL_LIGHTING)

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        glColor(1.0, 1.0,1.0)  

        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); 
        glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.texColorVolume )

        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0,0) #,0.5)
        glVertex2f(-1.0, -1.0); 
        glTexCoord2f(1,0) #,0.5)
        glVertex2f(1.0, -1.0);
        glTexCoord2f(1,1) #,0.5)
        glVertex2f(1.0, 1.0);
        glTexCoord2f(0,1) #,0.5)
        glVertex2f(-1.0, 1.0);
        glEnd();
        glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0 )



    def resizeGL(self, widthInPixels, heightInPixels):
        if ((widthInPixels is not self.uWidth) or (heightInPixels is not self.uHeight)):        
            self.uWidth = widthInPixels
            self.uHeight = heightInPixels

            glViewport(0, 0, widthInPixels, heightInPixels)
            self.update()


class TestImageLoadStore2D(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('TestImageLoadStore2D')
        self.statusBar().showMessage("Hello there")

        exit = QtGui.QAction("Exit", self)
        exit.setShortcut("Ctrl+Q")
        exit.setStatusTip('Exit application')
        self.connect(exit, QtCore.SIGNAL('triggered()'), QtCore.SLOT('close()'))


        self.viewer3D = Viewer3DWidget(self)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.viewer3D)

        self.resize(500,500)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        event.accept()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # app = QtGui.QApplication(['Python Qt OpenGL Demo'])
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = TestImageLoadStore2D()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

while the non-working 3D version is as following:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt4.QtOpenGL import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
import sys
iTexSize = 256


_vsClearSource =  """
    #version 440 compatibility
    void main() {
        gl_Position = ftransform();
        gl_FrontColor = gl_Color;
    }
    """     

_fsClearSource =   """
#version 440 compatibility
uniform int         iPrimitiveCount;
uniform int         iSliceIndex;

layout(size4x32, binding=0) writeonly uniform   image3D volColorVolume;
//layout(rgba32f, binding=0) writeonly uniform   image3D volColorVolume;
const int iMaxTexSize = 255;  

void main() {
    ivec3 ivecVolumeCoordinate = ivec3(gl_FragCoord.x, gl_FragCoord.y, 0); //iSliceIndex);

    vec4 vecVolumeValue =  vec4(0,1,0,1); // vec4(         float(iSlabIndex)/float(iPrimitiveCount)); //,0.0,0.0,0.0);

   imageStore(volColorVolume, ivecVolumeCoordinate, vecVolumeValue); 
   memoryBarrier();                 
   gl_FragData[0] = vec4(1,0,1,1);
}    
    """    

_fsFillSource =   """
#version 440 compatibility
uniform int         iPrimitiveCount;
uniform int         iSliceIndex;

layout(size4x32, binding=0) writeonly uniform   image3D volColorVolume;
const int iMaxTexSize = 255;  

void main() {
    ivec3 ivecVolumeCoordinate = ivec3(gl_FragCoord.x, gl_FragCoord.y, 0); //iSliceIndex);

    vec4 vecVolumeValue =  vec4( float(gl_FragCoord.x)  / float(iMaxTexSize)  , float(gl_FragCoord.y)  / float(iMaxTexSize)  , float(iSliceIndex)/float(iPrimitiveCount) ,  1  );

   imageStore(volColorVolume, ivecVolumeCoordinate, vecVolumeValue);   
   memoryBarrier();               
   gl_FragData[0] = vec4(1,0,1,1);
}    
"""       



class Viewer3DWidget(QGLWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        QGLWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.uWidth = 0
        self.uHeight = 0

        self.texColorTexture = None
        self.fboRendering    = None
        self.texColorVolume = None

        self.vecBackgroundColor = (1.,1.,1.)

        self.vecDrawBuffers = [ GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 , GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1 , GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT3, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT4, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT5 ]


        self.fSurfacesSpacing = 1.0
        self.fSurfacesTransparency = 1.0
        self.fZCoord = 0.0


    def setZCoordinate(self, fZCoordinate):
        self.fZCoord = fZCoordinate
        self.update()



    def initializeGL(self):
        self.shaShaderFill = QGLShaderProgram(self.context())
        self.shaShaderFill.addShaderFromSourceCode(QGLShader.Vertex, _vsClearSource)
        self.shaShaderFill.addShaderFromSourceCode(QGLShader.Fragment, _fsFillSource)   
        self.shaShaderFill.link()      

        self.shaShaderClear = QGLShaderProgram(self.context())
        self.shaShaderClear.addShaderFromSourceCode(QGLShader.Vertex, _vsClearSource)
        self.shaShaderClear.addShaderFromSourceCode(QGLShader.Fragment, _fsClearSource)   
        self.shaShaderClear.link()       



        glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
        glClearDepth(1.0)


    def initRenderTargets(self):
        global iTexSize
        if (self.texColorTexture is None):
            self.texColorTexture = glGenTextures( 1 )
        if (self.fboRendering is  None):
            self.fboRendering = glGenFramebuffers(1)               

        glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, self.texColorTexture )
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP)
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP)
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, 0, GL_RGBA32F, iTexSize, iTexSize, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, None)


        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, 0);

        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, self.fboRendering)
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE,  self.texColorTexture, 0)
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0)    


    def deleteRenderTargets(self):
        if (self.fboAccumulation is  not  None):
            glDeleteFramebuffers(1,self.fboRendering)          
            self.fboAccumulation = None
        if (self.texColorTexture is not None):
            glDeleteTextures( self.texColorTexture )
            self.texColorTexture = None


    def initColorVolume(self):
        if (self.texColorVolume is None):
            self.texColorVolume = glGenTextures( 1 )


        glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_3D, self.texColorVolume )
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP)
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP)
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP)
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
        glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, iTexSize, iTexSize, iTexSize, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, None);


        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0);    



    def fillVolume(self, bClear):
        global iTexSize

        shaShader = self.shaShaderClear
        if(not bClear):
            shaShader = self.shaShaderFill

        if (not self.fboRendering):
            self.initRenderTargets() 

        if (not self.texColorVolume):
            self.initColorVolume()

        glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION )
        glLoadIdentity()

        glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
        glLoadIdentity();            



        glBindImageTexture(0,self.texColorVolume,0,GL_FALSE,0,GL_WRITE_ONLY,GL_RGBA32F);

        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, self.fboRendering);
        glDrawBuffers(1, self.vecDrawBuffers);

        glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);            

        shaShader.bind()

        shaShader.setUniformValue("iPrimitiveCount", iTexSize)  
        shaShader.setUniformValue("volColorVolume", 0) 

        for i in range(iTexSize):


            shaShader.setUniformValue("iSliceIndex", i) 




            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glVertex2f(-1.0, -1.0); 
            glVertex2f(1.0, -1.0);
            glVertex2f(1.0, 1.0);
            glVertex2f(-1.0, 1.0);
            glEnd();


            #sync
            glMemoryBarrier(GL_ALL_BARRIER_BITS);
        glMemoryBarrier(GL_ALL_BARRIER_BITS);

        glBindImageTexture(0,0,0,GL_FALSE,0,GL_WRITE_ONLY,GL_RGBA32F);
        shaShader.release()

        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);


    def paintGL(self):
        if  (self.uWidth is 0):
            return           
        if (not self.fboRendering):
            self.initRenderTargets() 
            self.initColorVolume()

        glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION )
        glLoadIdentity()

        glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
        glLoadIdentity();

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)


        self.fillVolume(True)
        #draw into the volume
        #self.fillVolume(False)

        #slice the volume
        self.displayTexture()



        glFlush()




    def displayTexture(self):   #essentially not useable here
        glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION )
        glLoadIdentity()
        glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
        glLoadIdentity();
        glDisable(GL_BLEND)
        glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);  
        glDisable(GL_LIGHTING)

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        glColor(1.0, 1.0,1.0)  

        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_3D); 
        glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_3D, self.texColorVolume )

        fZCoord = self.fZCoord        

        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord3f(0,0,fZCoord)
        glVertex2f(-1.0, -1.0); 
        glTexCoord3f(1,0,fZCoord)
        glVertex2f(1.0, -1.0);
        glTexCoord3f(1,1,fZCoord)
        glVertex2f(1.0, 1.0);
        glTexCoord3f(0,1,fZCoord)
        glVertex2f(-1.0, 1.0);
        glEnd();
        glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0 )



    def resizeGL(self, widthInPixels, heightInPixels):
        if ((widthInPixels is not self.uWidth) or (heightInPixels is not self.uHeight)):        
            self.uWidth = widthInPixels
            self.uHeight = heightInPixels

            glViewport(0, 0, widthInPixels, heightInPixels)
            self.update()





class TestImageLoadStore3D(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('TestImageLoadStore3D')
        self.statusBar().showMessage("Hello there")

        exit = QtGui.QAction("Exit", self)
        exit.setShortcut("Ctrl+Q")
        exit.setStatusTip('Exit application')
        self.connect(exit, QtCore.SIGNAL('triggered()'), QtCore.SLOT('close()'))


        self.setToolTip('This is a window, or <b>something</b>')

        self.viewer3D = Viewer3DWidget(self)

        parentWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        slider1 = QtGui.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, None)
        slider1.setRange(0,10000)
        slider1.setValue(5000)
        slider1.setMaximumWidth(120)
        slider1.valueChanged.connect(self.slider1Handler)
        vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(slider1)
        vbox.addStretch(1)
        self.viewer3D.setSizePolicy( QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding )
        hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addLayout(vbox)
        hbox.addWidget(self.viewer3D)

        parentWidget.setLayout(hbox)        
        self.setCentralWidget(parentWidget)


        self.resize(500,500)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        event.accept()
    def slider1Handler(self, iVal):    
        fVal = iVal / 10000.0
        #print "zcoord: ",fVal
        self.viewer3D.setZCoordinate(fVal)           

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # app = QtGui.QApplication(['Python Qt OpenGL Demo'])
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = TestImageLoadStore3D()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

the code is not extra neat, also because i copy/pasted/modified some older pyopengl code i had.
The problem is that the values written in the 3D texture make absolute no sense.
I ran it using the latest version of PyOpenGL (the experimental one), a Quadro K5000 and the latest drivers (332.76), that also provide the support for OpenGL 4.4 .

I'm not sure what i might be doing wrong, also because i haven't found many examples of writing into 3D textures (actually none, and i also looked in the latest version of the red book)

Can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is here in your frag shader:

```
layout(size4x32, binding=0) writeonly uniform   image3D volColorVolume;
```

You are binding the 3D texture via

```
glBindImageTexture(0,self.texColorVolume,0,GL_FALSE,0,GL_WRITE_ONLY,GL_RGBA32F);
```

Let me quote from the OpenGL 4.4 spec, section 8.26 "Texture Image Loads and Stores" (emphasis mine):

> If the texture identified by texture is a one-dimensional array,
>   two-dimensional array, three-dimensional, cube map, cube map array, or
>   two-dimensional multisample array texture, it is possible to bind
>   either the entire texture level or a single layer or face of the
>   texture level. If layered is TRUE, the entire level is bound. If
>   layered is FALSE, only the single layer identified by layer will be
>   bound. **When layered is FALSE, the single bound layer is treated as a
>   different texture target for image accesses:**
>
> - one-dimensional array texture layers are treated as one-dimensional textures;
> - two-dimensional array, **three-dimensional**, cube map, cube map array **texture layers are treated as two-dimensional textures**; and
> - two-dimensional multisample array textures are treated as two-dimensional multisample textures.

So, if you just bind one layer of a 3D texture with the `layered` parameter set to `GL_FALSE` (as you are currently doing), it will act as if it is just a 2D texture, so either just use an `image2D` and access it with 2D coords, or bind it with `layered` set to `GL_TRUE` and a valid range of layers you will be able to write into a specific layer/slices of your texture using an `image3D` and 3-dimensional image coordinates.

Comment: thanks a lot! this was indeed the mistake, due to my misunderstanding of the doc. now it works perfectly :)

Answer (score -3):

you have like 60 semicolons in python. Python doesn't use semicolons. In fact, I'm pretty sure python is the only programming language that actually doesn't use semicolons.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your answer seems more appropriate as a comment and does not answer the OP's question. Besides semicolons have no side effects in Python. [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236380/why-is-semicolon-allowed-in-this-python-snippet)

Comment: yeah sorry, i was a toxic kid back then, please excuse my comment