# Silent output ipython notebook for matplotlib basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, matplotlib-basemap

i'm trying to plot basemap with ipython notebook.This is my code and the output:

[image]

There's actually no error, but I just want a more silent output, output map only instead of map and bunch of `<matplotlib.patches.Polygon object at 0x118317250>`.

What should I do to avoid this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a final semicolon `;` to the last line in the cell.

Comment: If you are interested in the reason it works, I've just written [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29094034/2749397) to another question where I try to explain why adding a semicol does the trick.