# No connection adapters were found for Python3-Requests

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I am using beautiful soup with requests package in python3 for web scraping. This is my code.

```
import csv  
from datetime import datetime
import requests
import csv  
from datetime import datetime 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


quote_page = ['http://10.69.161.179:8080'];

data = []

page = requests.get(quote_page)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')

name_box = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'caption span10'})

name= name_box.text.strip() #strip() is used to remove starting and ending

print(name);

data.append(name)

    

with open('sample.csv', 'a') as csv_file:  
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerow([name])

print ("Success");
```

When I execute the above code I'm getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "first_try.py", line 21, in <module>
    page = requests.get(quote_page);
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests-2.13.0-py3.6.egg\requests\api.py", line 70, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests-2.13.0-py3.6.egg\requests\api.py", line 56, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests-2.13.0-py3.6.egg\requests\sessions.py", line 488, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests-2.13.0-py3.6.egg\requests\sessions.py", line 603, in send
    adapter = self.get_adapter(url=request.url)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests-2.13.0-py3.6.egg\requests\sessions.py", line 685, in get_adapter
    raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url)
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '['http://10.69.161.179:8080/#/main/dashboard/metrics']'
```

Can anyone help me with this? :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because requests.get() only accept url schema in string format. You need to unpack string inside the list [] .

```
quote_page = ['http://10.69.161.179:8080']
for url in quote_page:
  page = requests.get(url)
  .....
```

By the way , though semicolon is harmless under following statement, you should avoid it unless [you need it for some reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236380/why-is-semicolon-allowed-in-this-python-snippet)

```
quote_page = ['http://10.69.161.179:8080'];
```