# possible "if" syntaxes in Python3

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax

I´d like to know if there´s a way to shorten an "if", that contains more than one command.

I know you can do it for single command if´s like:

```
if x > y:
   print("normal if")
```

and it becomes:

```
if x > y: print("shortened if")
```

But how could it be done in this case, for example?

```
if x > y:
   print("normal if")
   some_number *= 2
```

Comment: why do you want to "shorten" it? What's the benefit?

Comment: just out of curiosity. But i think it would be useful for a huge enough file that has thousands of these "if´s", to make it smaller (that´s just a feeling tho, i can´t say it for sure)

Comment: If you really want to put it into a single line you can use semicolons, e.g.: `if x > y: print("normal if"); some_number *= 2` but I would really recommend against it. It just makes it harder to read (without any benefit I can think of)

Comment: Python is all about readability and clarity. Why would you want to avoid that?

Comment: @MartijnPieters i just wanted to know really, i don´t intend to use it in my codes.

Comment: @MateusBuarque the case of "I have thousands of these ifs" is arguably exactly where you should *avoid* doing that. The indent makes it very readable, a single-line `if` is much harder to notice when looking through the code.

Comment: Is it possible to post a bigger part of the code?

Comment: Is the `print` part of the code absolutely necessary?

Comment: @Elmex80s it was just an example. And, yes, sometimes you do need more than 1 line inside of an if.

Answer (score 4):

You can shorten the command if you use a semicolon. See the behavior of a [python semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236380/why-is-semicolon-allowed-in-this-python-snippet)

```
if x > y:
   print("normal if")
   some_number *= 2
```

Can be shortened to

```
if x > y: print("normal_if"); some_number *= 2
```

I am not saying that this is the right thing to do but it is possible. I recommend against it since it is harder to read.