# Send data from python script to a webpage (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, python

Is there a way to send data from a python script to a webpage and process it using JavaScript?

I found the `python-requests` module but it seems that it only send data to the server-side not to the client-side.

Comment: Hopefully this link whill help sory if it doesn't. [Press this!][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460938/how-to-run-python-script-in-webpage

Comment: I suggest you look into AJAX: you'll have to make the call from javascript to python. Once you've made that call, you could open a websocket if you need to keep it open. Take a look here for example: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/webservers.html