# How can I run a Python script in HTML?

Tags: python, html, web

Currently I have some Python files which connect to an [SQLite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) database for user inputs and then perform some calculations which set the output of the program. I'm new to Python web programming and I want to know: What is the best method to use Python on the web?

Example: I want to run my Python files when the user clicks a button on the web page. Is it possible?

I started with [Django](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29). But it needs some time for the learning. And I also saw something called [CGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) scripts. Which option should I use?

Comment: Please check this link:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460938/how-to-run-python-script-in-webpage

Comment: The suggested duplicate is *[How to run a Python script in a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460938/)*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It probably would depend on what you want to do. I personally use CGI and it might be simpler if your inputs from the web page are simple, and it takes less time to learn. Here are some resources for it:

- *[cgi — Common Gateway Interface support](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html)*
- *[Python - CGI Programming](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_cgi_programming.htm)*

However, you may still have to do some configuring to allow it to run the program instead of displaying it.

Here's a tutorial on that: *[Apache Tutorial: Dynamic Content with CGI](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/cgi.html)*

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I went through the example and it's something similar which i'm looking for. But is there a directory structure I need to follow to keep my files? How can I run files? Please clarify.

Comment: I kept all my CGI programs in a directory (`cgi-bin`) and configured that directory so that the programs are executed. I'll edit to add a link to the tutorial.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I started running programs in cgi.

Comment: No problem! Good luck!

Comment: @abacles This implies running a server, right?

Comment: @AndrewAnderson yeah, I think so

Comment: Isn't CGI completely outdated?

Comment: @PeterMortensen You're right, something like Flask may be a better approach today.

Answer (score 17):

You are able to run a Python file using HTML using [PHP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP).

Add a PHP file as *index.php*:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Run my Python files</title>
<?PHP
echo shell_exec("python test.py 'parameter1'");
?>
</head>
```

#### Passing the parameter to Python

Create a Python file as *test.py*:

```
import sys
input=sys.argv[1]
print(input)
```

Print the parameter passed by PHP.

Comment: Neat! To support spaces in your argument, try doing this instead: `echo shell_exec("python test.py \"Parameter 1\"");`

Comment: There is a whole lot of context missing here (for example, prerequisites). On some Linux server somewhere? Where? Running locally? On a Linux computer? With both the PHP and Python interpreters installed? Where and with what versions was this tested? Please respond by [edit]ing (changing) your answer, not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to [WebAssembly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebAssembly) and the [Pyodide](https://github.com/pyodide/pyodide) project, it is now possible to run Python in the browser. Check out this [tutorial](https://karay.me/2022/07/12/bringing-python-to-the-web.html) on it.

**Update: Pyodide v0.21.0**

```js
(async () => { // create anonymous async function to enable await

  var output = document.getElementById("output")
  var code = document.getElementById("code")
  
  output.value = 'Initializing...\n'

  window.pyodide = await loadPyodide({stdout: addToOutput, stderr: addToOutput}) // redirect stdout and stderr to addToOutput
        output.value += 'Ready!\n' 
})()


function addToOutput(s) {
  output.value += `${s}\n`
  output.scrollTop = output.scrollHeight
}

async function evaluatePython() {
  addToOutput(`>>>${code.value}`)

  await pyodide.loadPackagesFromImports(code.value, addToOutput, addToOutput)
  try {
    let result = await pyodide.runPythonAsync(code.value)
    addToOutput(`${result}`)
  }
  catch (e) {
    addToOutput(`${e}`)
  }
  code.value = ''
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/pyodide/v0.21.3/full/pyodide.js"></script>

Output:
<textarea id="output" style="width: 100%;" rows="10" disabled=""></textarea>
<textarea id="code" rows="3">import numpy as np
np.ones((10,))
</textarea>
<button id="run" onclick="evaluatePython()">Run</button>
```

---

**Old answer (related to Pyodide v0.15.0)**

```js
const output = document.getElementById("output")
const code = document.getElementById("code")

function addToOutput(s) {
    output.value += `>>>${code.value}\n${s}\n`
    output.scrollTop = output.scrollHeight
    code.value = ''
}

output.value = 'Initializing...\n'
// Init pyodide
languagePluginLoader.then(() => { output.value += 'Ready!\n' })

function evaluatePython() {
    pyodide.runPythonAsync(code.value)
        .then(output => addToOutput(output))
        .catch((err) => { addToOutput(err) })
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Default Pyodide files URL ('packages.json', 'pyodide.asm.data', etc.)
        window.languagePluginUrl = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/pyodide//v0.15.0/full/';
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/pyodide//v0.15.0/full/pyodide.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    Output:
    </div>
    <textarea id='output' style='width: 100%;' rows='10' disabled></textarea>
    <textarea id='code' rows='3'>
import numpy as np
np.ones((10,))
    </textarea>
    <button id='run' onclick='evaluatePython()'>Run</button>
    <p>You can execute any Python code. Just enter something
       in the box above and click the button.
       <strong>It can take some time</strong>.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: test snippet is no longer working

Comment: Great! Nice work with an interesting toolkit.

Answer (score 3):

If your web server is [Apache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) you can use the
[mod_python](http://modpython.org/) module in order to run your Python CGI scripts.

For [nginx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx), you can use *[mod_wsgi](http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/)*.

Comment: The mod_python project is long dead and shouldn't be used for anything new. The option for Apache, not nginx as you have it, is mod_wsgi, but the Google Code site is old site which is no longer used, use http://www.modwsgi.org instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do it with [Flask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flask_%28web_framework%29)!

#### Installation

First you have to type `pip install flask`.

#### Setup

You said when a user clicks on a link you want it to execute a Python script

```
from flask import *
# Importing all the methods, classes, functions from Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

# This is the first page that comes when you
# type localhost:5000... it will have a tag
# that redirects to a page
@app.route("/")
def  HomePage():
    return "<a href='/runscript'>EXECUTE SCRIPT </a>"

# Once it redirects here (to localhost:5000/runscript),
# it will run the code before the return statement
@app.route("/runscript")
def ScriptPage():
    # Type what you want to do when the user clicks on the link.
    #
    # Once it is done with doing that code... it will
    # redirect back to the homepage
    return redirect(url_for("HomePage"))

# Running it only if we are running it directly
# from the file... not by importing
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a new tool, [PyScript](https://github.com/pyscript/pyscript), which might be helpful for that.

[Official website](https://pyscript.net/)

[GitHub repository](https://github.com/pyscript/pyscript)

Comment: The examples in that GitHub repository are actively available to try online at https://pyscript.net/examples/ .

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31730773)

Comment: This project is also based on [Pyodide](https://github.com/pyodide/pyodide)

Answer (score 0):

You can't run Python code directly

You may use *[Python Inside HTML](http://karrigell.sourceforge.net/en/pythoninsidehtml.html)*.

Or for inside [PHP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) this:

```
http://www.skulpt.org/
```

Comment: The second link is broken (DNS domain expiry?): *"Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site.. We can’t connect to the server at www.skulpt.org."*

Answer (score 0):

You should try the [Flask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flask_%28web_framework%29) or [Django](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29) frameworks. They are used to integrate Python and HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Py Code because it could run Any python script In html Like this:

```html
<py-script>print("Python in Html!")<py-script>
```

Im not sure if it could run modules like Ursina engine ect But what i know is
That It allows you to type Python in Html. You can check out its offical Site for more info.

Comment: You are probably referring to PyScript. But that answer has already been given.